# How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git

Tags: git, corruption

After `git init`, I added and committed a few files, made some changes, added and committed.  Set up the git daemon (running under Cygwin on WinXP) and cloned the repository once.
Now, I get this error with the cloned repository:

```
$ git status
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Is there any way to fix this, other than getting a new copy of the repository?

Comment: Is this in the cloned repository, or in the original repository? Did the clone command output any errors?

Answer (score 1689, accepted):

If the problem is with the index as **the staging area for commits** (i.e. `.git/index`), you can simply remove the index (make a backup copy if you want), and then restore index to version in the last commit:

On OSX/Linux/Windows(With Git bash):

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

On Windows (with CMD and not git bash):

```
del .git\index
git reset
```

(The `reset` command above is the same as  `git reset --mixed HEAD`)

You can alternatively use lower level [plumbing](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-1.html) `git read-tree` instead of `git reset`.

---

If the problem is with **index for [packfile](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles)**, you can recover it using `git index-pack`.

Comment: I accidentally did a `:w!` in a `:Gstatus` (from fugitive.vim). This answer saved me a lot of hair pulling.

Comment: I know we don't like "me too" messages -- but "me too". Equivalent in Windows is `erase /s .git\index`, I needed a `erase .git\index.lock` too.

Comment: I had to use rm .git/index as I received an ambiguous warning using -f

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem with find and replace but git reset tells me there are two pack files in .git/objects/pack/ that can't be accessed. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: wouldn't it be safer to use `git reset --keep` instead?
In the [Tower Git Cheat Sheet](http://www.git-tower.com/files/cheatsheet/Git_Cheat_Sheet_grey.pdf) it is explained as:
_Reset your HEAD pointer to a previous commit and preserve uncommitted local changes_

Comment: It didn't exist when I was writing this answer... Anyway `git reset --keep` is safer form of **`git reset --hard`**; `git reset --mixed` doesn't touch workdir at all.

Comment: Nothing changed for me... version `1.9.1`

Comment: How can you tell if it's a problem with the *Staging Area* or the *Packfile*?

Comment: Are those commands issued from the Windows CMD prompt or from the BASH Git command prompt?

Comment: Followed first instructions Windows.  Did not resolve problem. Followed second instructions but got a response (for git index-pack) with usage info. Apparently Git needs some parameter supplied. Tried 'git reset --keep' and got error : You do not have a valid HEAD. fatal: could not reset index file to revision HEAD. Now my "view log" doesn't even work.

Comment: @ClayNichols: neither of those instructions affects HEAD, so your problem is unrelated to the index. If `git log <branch>` works, or `git show <some commit>` works, or if it is something in `.git/logs/` you should be able to recover at least some of history... and there is also `git fsck --lost-found`.

Comment: worked perfectly for me. tried those commands in git shell of gitHub

Comment: For me on Windows it was rm .git/index and after git reset --keep

Comment: I had to do a `git checkout .` on the repository root after because it kept saying that some files were modified (`git diff`was of no help because it treated the files as binary).

Comment: The `git reset` fails with `fatal: loose object <uuis> (stored in .git/objects/b2/<uuid>) is corrupt`.

Comment: Folks doubting if there changes will be deleted , no they will be not after doing "git reset" .

Comment: I manually deleted the index file under the.git folder and then did "git reset" and it worked for me.

Comment: Got this error on VS code after the update and just used the CMD to run the commands and successfully reset the index

Comment: The fun in getting to the same helpful answer again, and see that I already upvoted last time =]

Comment: @Pjetr `git reset --keep` also throws `fatal: index file corrupt`

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 78):

You may have accidentally corrupted the .git/index file with a sed on your project root (refactoring perhaps?) with something like:

```
sed -ri -e "s/$SEACHPATTERN/$REPLACEMENTTEXT/g" $(grep -Elr "$SEARCHPATERN" "$PROJECTROOT")
```

to avoid this in the future, just ignore binary files with your grep/sed:

```
sed -ri -e "s/$SEACHPATTERN/$REPLACEMENTTEXT/g" $(grep -Elr --binary-files=without-match "$SEARCHPATERN" "$PROJECTROOT")
```

Comment: If you don't mind losing changes in `.git/index`, you can always delete it and recreate with `git reset` (without `--hard`!).

Comment: I broke it with  # find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/Politician/Legislator/g' {} \;  Doing what this answer recommends this would have not broken it in the first place, but the accepted answer repaired the damage that I did do.  This is excellent prevention though.

Comment: @RyanMortensen You could try inverting your `sed` with something like `find .git/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/Legislator/Politician/g' {} \;`  This might help if your `.git/` is so corrupted that `git reset` won't work. Or maybe you want to restore your existing `.git/index` without deleting it.  This will fail, of course, if your original code or index already had some "Legislator"s in it.

Comment: Thank you @hobs you saved me a lot of trouble - I solved it by inverting the `sed` by replacing my `new_string` with my `old_string`!

Comment: I refactored my whole project instead of the 'src' folder in IntelliJ and had this problem. This explains why I had such strange errors!

Answer (score 31):

I had that problem, and I try ti fix with this:

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

BUT it did not work. **The solution**?
For some reason I had others .git folders in sub directories. I delete those .git folders (not the principal) and `git reset` again. Once they were deleted, everything worked again.

Comment: This answer really resolve problem if you have some .git folders in vendor/ (e.x.)

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DynoCris im sure the rm command is for osx/linux... try the other answer above

Answer (score 21):

This sounds like a bad clone. You could try the following to get (possibly?) more information:

```
git fsck --full
```

Answer (score 18):

Since the above solutions left me with continued problems, I used this dull solution:

1. clone a new copy of the repo elsewhere
2. copy the fresh .git directory into the (broken) repo that contained the changes I wanted to commit

Did the trick. Btw, I did a `sed` on the project root as @hobs guessed. Learned my lesson.

Comment: That's brilliant :)

Comment: It's not really brilliant if you were in the middle of a merge, had created branches or had issued any commits since cloning, or any of a number of other scenarios... Cloning a new copy of the repo is hardly a solution and I daresay it smacks of impatience (best left when in a true pinch). It's much better to actually diagnose what's going on and repair the existing repo's index--that's usually relatively easy to do. Sometimes you can just rename the index file (or delete it, if you're sure you won't ever need it again) and let Git create a new one (using git-reset or git-checkout)..

Comment: Only solution of all the suggestions that actually worked without major extra steps! Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me.  Although i'm curious of the reason I started getting the errors in the first place.  When I logged out yesterday, it was fine.  Log in this morning, it wasn't.

```
rm .git/index

git reset
```

Comment: This worked for me, Although It removed all added files from git. I had to run git add for those files

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Note for git submodule users - the solutions here will not work for you as-is.

Let's say you have a parent repository called `dev`, for example, and your submodule repository is called `api`.

if you are inside of `api` and you get the error mentioned in this question:

`error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt`

The `index` file will NOT be inside of a `.git` folder.  In fact, the `.git` won't even be a folder - it will will be a text document with the location of the real .git data for this repository. Likely something like this:

`~/dev/api $ cat .git
gitdir: ../.git/modules/api`

So, instead of `rm -f .git/index`, you will need to do this:

`rm -f ../.git/modules/api/index
git reset`

or, more generally,

`rm -f ../.git/modules/INSERT_YOUR_REPO_NAME_HERE/index
git reset`

Answer (score 5):

This issue can occur when there is a `.git` directory underneath one of the subdirectories.  To fix it, check if there are other .git directories there, and remove them and try again.

Comment: Several other answers have already provided this information.

Answer (score 5):

Use this if you want to keep your last changed files

```
rm -f .git/index
git read-tree HEAD
```

Comment: thanks! your ans works for me. above all answers forcibly removing the index file but still getting the same error. just saved my night!!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is occoured due to changes in git file or brach.
Then you need to run this command on your **cmd**.

1. **del .git\index**
2. **git reset --hard**

After run 2 commands your Git Repo is working well

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers worked for me.

I was using worktrees, so there is no .git folder.

You'll need to go back to your main repo. Inside that, delete .git/worktrees/<name_of_tree>/index

Then run git reset as per other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning remote repo and replacing the .git folder from it to problematic local directory solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I committed my changes and suddenly my laptop went off due to battery issue and then I got this fatal index corrupt error and Desktop github couldn't locate this git repo. So I ran below mentioned commands using git-bash and everything went back fine.

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

Answer (score 0):

A repo may seem corrupted if you mix different `git` versions.

Local repositories touched by new git versions aren't backwards-compatible with old git versions. New git repos look corrupted to old git versions (in my case git 2.28 broke repo for git 2.11).

Updating old git version may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows PowerShell, it should be

```
rm -Force .git/index
git reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and attempted to fix it as described in the accepted answer. However, **immediately after resetting my index in `.git/index` it became corrupted again**.

The problem was, that I was using `git bisect` yesterday to find a bug, but forgot to run `git bisect reset` to clean up afterwards at the end of the day. Today as I started making changes git got confused, as it was **still in bisect mode** and I was attempting to apply changes. I also couldn't just run `git bisect reset`, because there were already changes.

To fix this problem run the following in the git bash in your root directory:

```
git stash -m <message>
git bisect reset        # You are now most likely in detached head mode
git checkout <branch>
git stash apply         # If you have multiple stashes, make sure 
                          to apply the correct one
```

Note that there is **no need to remove `.git/index`** and reset the index **in this case**!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps.

1. manually delete the index file from .git folder
2. Run the command in your project directory `git reset`

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me due to a BSOD during a `git push`, I tried `rm -f .git/index`, followed by `git reset`, but that made git think all the files on the branch were untracked

Solution: re-clone and manually copy your changes over onto the new clone (eg Winmerge)

Answer (score -2):

I did a simple trick. I clone the repo to a new folder. Copied the .git folder from the new folder to repo's old folder, replacing .git there.

Comment: Very dangerous because it will delete data like unpublished commits, tags and branches as well as stashes and the reflog.

Comment: Not sure about unpublished commits as I believe they are stored in .git folder and I copied .git folder. I didn't lose anything with this method. I don't know about stashes and reflog to make any comments on that.

Comment: You‘re correct, but maybe you should emphasize that you did a local clone. But my comment ist still true for stashes and reflog.

Comment: Okay, I don't have any experience on that comment anything further, however, it worked for me and some users might find it useful. There no need to downvote it.

Answer (score -4):

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

More info at https://www.chris-shaw.com/blog/quick-fix-for-git-corrupt-index

Comment: Several other answers have already provided this information.

Answer (score -9):

You can also try for restore to previous version of the file (if you are using windows os)

Comment: Don't put answer you don't know.