# Error: fatal loose object ### (stored in .git/objects/.... is corrupt)

Tags: git, gitk

I just fired up `gitk` as usual but this time I received a fatal error message:

```
fatal: loose object 58008283f6ad152ac44a1b6da961795ababe5b93 (stored in .git/objects/58/008283f6ad152ac44a1b6da961795ababe5b93) is corrupt
fatal: loose object 58008283f6ad152ac44a1b6da961795ababe5b93 (stored in .git/objects/58/008283f6ad152ac44a1b6da961795ababe5b93) is corrupt
    while executing
"close $gdtf"
    (procedure "gettreediffline" line 36)
    invoked from within
"gettreediffline file1071e148 58008283f6ad152ac44a1b6da961795ababe5b93"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $script"
    (procedure "dorunq" line 11)
    invoked from within
"dorunq"
    ("after" script)
```

I clicked OK on the error message box, exited `gitk`, then started `gitk` again -- this time it came up without any errors (just as usual).

What does this error mean and why did I receive it?

Should I start worrying about the integrity of my repository? (at this point still local, in a `.git` subdirectory)

**UPDATE:** I just ran `git fsck` as suggested below and I got:

```
git fsck
dangling blob 6302f0a93a8d793b473e1a1976f221827b595ed7
dangling blob 5246a9d7408b1d5d01e9c471a67c1f0866f0d626
dangling blob ec08d18657f37e5bbdbebc7dc25615037b532463
dangling blob 8b69b97bdc45f3c86405f67a5f396d122408ad64
dangling blob aa39e78673ec3f2cb575798be1d2b4555c637475
```

1. What does "dangling blob" mean?
2. How could this have happened?
3. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: sound like a good opportunity to run `git fsck` [link](http://book.git-scm.com/4_maintaining_git.html)

Comment: @Fredrik Thanks for this tip. I didn't know about `git fsck` until now. I just ran it and the results seem to point to a problem (or more). See update in my OP. What do I do now?

Comment: @WinWin the dangling blobs are not necessarily an issue.  They just state that you have blobs without anything pointing to them.  [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)

Comment: @Andy I just did `git show` on one of the objects and received 56,491 lines of text report... seems like a lose-lose situation LOL (I thought `git` would save me time). How do I decipher this?

Comment: Is there a clone of the repo somewhere?

Comment: @Andy No. only pushed it once, a while ago (mainly for learning, I don't need to share it yet).

Comment: The contents of the object are junk? or are they something that is in your tree?

Comment: Actually if the error doesn't show up anymore, it could have just been some corruption in memory.  If `git fsck` doesn't return any errors, I would guess that is what happened.  And make a backup of your repo:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `git fsck` is clean and you don't see the error anymore, I would venture to guess that there was some corruption in memory.

I know you said that you only have been working locally and don't want to share, but it is still a good idea to have a backup that is at least on a different disk and preferably a different physical location.  If you don't mind your project being open source you can use  [github](http://www.github.com) or free.

[Links on backing up a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D%20backup)