# git: dangling blobs

Tags: git, git-dangling

I recently ran `git fsck --lost-found` on my repository.

I expected to see a couple dangling commits, where I had reset `HEAD`.

However, I was surprised to see likely over several thousand dangling blob messages.

I don't believe anything is wrong with my repository, but I'm curious as to what causes these dangling blobs? There's only two people working on the repository, and we haven't done anything out of the ordinary.

I wouldn't think they were created by an older version of a file being replaced by a new one, since git would need to hold onto both blobs so it can display history.

Come to think of it, at one point we did add a VERY large directory (thousands of files) to the project by mistake and then remove it.  Might this be the source of all the dangling blobs?

Just looking for insight into this mystery.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Last time I looked at this I stumbled across [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20170211194735/http://git.net:80/ml/git/2009-04/msg01874.html), specifically this part:

> You can also end up with dangling objects in packs. When that pack is
>   repacked, those objects will be loosened, and then eventually expired
>   under the rule mentioned above. However, I believe gc will not always
>   repack old packs; it will make new packs until you have a lot of packs,
>   and then combine them all (at least that is what "gc --auto" will do; I
>   don't recall whether just "git gc" follows the same rule).

So it's normal behavior, and does get collected eventually, I believe.

edit: Per Daniel, you can immediately collect it by running

```
git gc --prune="0 days"
```

Comment: what will happen if those blob are remove?

Comment: @nferocious76 then you cannot salvage files that, for example, were added to staging but not committed, and were then removed (via rm -f). Once the GC has run the files are lost for good.

Comment: @DavidBrower I see thank you. So it also remove unlinked or unreferenced files.

Comment: git gc --prune=all

Answer (score 28):

I was really impatient and used:

```
git gc --prune="0 days"
```

Answer (score 16):

Whenever you `add` a file to the index, the content of that file are added to Git's object database as a blob. When you then `reset`/`rm --cached` that file, the blobs will still exist (they will be garbage collected the next time you run `gc`)

However, when those files are part of a commit and you decide later to `reset` history, then the old commits are still reachable from Git's reflog and will only be garbage collected after a period of time (usually a month, iirc). Those objects should not show up as dangling though, since they are still referenced from the reflog.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you fix up a file and re-`add` it, the previous one becomes a dangling blob in the same way.  (I generally use the sequence: hack away, `git add`, `git diff --cached` and/or `git status` until happy, then `git commit`, so I get a lot of these. :-) )