# Git - Unlink of file .idx and .pack failed (The only process owned handle to this file is git.exe)

Tags: git, unlink

Please, look at this picture![image]
could be git that stupid? Git couldn't unlink some file, but only git.exe is holding a handle to this file. (Permissions are ok - Full control)
Please, is there a safe solution for this problem?
My Git version is 1.9.5-preview20141217

Comment: Perhaps someone messed up the permissions on the file (or a subdirectory leading to the file) so that the user currently running `git` doesn't have permission to delete it...

Comment: Hi, I checked all permissions and there is "full control" for Admin, and I'm admin on this machine.

Comment: Hi, was there ever a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi, now I have a new PC and do not have this problem. So maybe the solution is checkout the git repository to new folder or maybe newer version of git fixed it.

Comment: That should no longer occur with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755262/6309).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) improves the file descriptors management for the packfiles, and avoid the "`Unlink of file... failed. Should I try again?`" error message.

See [commit 12e73a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12e73a3ce46135279cec8fc9ef0068948936e6f8) (09 Jul 2018) by [Kim Gybels (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 562413e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/562413eb2938b7a1aa85a2ae157ef162d51e55dc), 02 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `gc --auto`: release pack files before auto packing

> "`git gc --auto`" opens file descriptors for the packfiles before spawning "`git repack`/`prune`", which would upset Windows that does not want a process to work on a file that is open by another process.

> Teach `gc --auto` to release pack files *before* auto packing the repository
> to prevent failures when removing them.

> Also teach the test 'fetching with auto-gc does not lock up' to complain
> when it is no longer triggering an auto packing of the repository.

This solves the [Git for Windows issue "Unlink of file `XXX` failed. Should I try again?"](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/500), with [PR 1769](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1769).

---

Another improvement: With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the run-command API has been updated so that the callers can easily ask the file descriptors open for packfiles to be closed immediately before spawning commands that may trigger `auto-gc`.

See [commit c4dee2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4dee2c0851f3a6b202afd2c9d979ed417f4bcdc), [commit 5a22a33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a22a334cb757753230f1d73da36130513016830), [commit 28d04e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28d04e1ec19777bf6382d016b6e624d0ff4336cd), [commit 3322a9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3322a9d87f3b2121d2c62096f9261c8934c74056) (09 Sep 2021), and [commit 7e44ff7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e44ff7a3983ad0c7be5c9edcfea2e8355ce9a65), [commit 957ba81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/957ba814bf93b698742ffa3cf37e4f665ed95b45) (08 Sep 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c042ad5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c042ad5ad58d4e43aadc806850e76fef73848d2c), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`c4dee2c085`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4dee2c0851f3a6b202afd2c9d979ed417f4bcdc):Close object store closer to spawning child processes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In many cases where we spawned child processes that *may* trigger a repack, we explicitly closed the object store first (so that the `repack` process can delete the `.pack` files, which would otherwise not be possible on Windows since files cannot be deleted as long as they as still in use).
>
> Wherever possible, we now use the new `close_object_store` bit of the `run_command()` API, to delay closing the object store even further.
> This makes the code easier to maintain because it is now more obvious that we only release those file handles because of those child processes.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and solved it by the command : `git gc` The above command remove temp and unnecessary files (Garbage Collector): https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229658/532575