# Why is Git clean -fdx blocked by a Process that Process Explorer can't find?

Tags: git, process-explorer

I'm using `git clean -fdx` on my repo using `Git 2.8.2.windows.1`. My understanding is that the `-f` flag should be forcing removal. At times I - unexpectedly - get [this linking issue (that has a solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181057/unlink-of-file-failed).

My question is not why this happens - I know another process has a handle on whatever file Git is trying to manipulate.

**My question**: When I look up the path that `git clean -fdx` complains about using `Process Explorer->Find`, no handles are found. **How can this be?**

What other tools can be used to determine which process is locking things up?

Comment: Check if the issue persists with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755262/6309