# Removing unwanted folders from git repo permanently - Repo size not changing

Tags: git

I have git repo, I have accidentally committed some library files to the git remote repo.

Now it has resulted in increased size of about 6.23 GB. Then I tried deleting the library using the following commands

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch node_modules" -- --all

rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Now the library has been removed from the repository and it is not listed in the repo folders. But still the size of the local repo is bigger as before

One more thing is it takes a lot of time to execute the above commands. I am not sure whether they worked properly

I even did try pushing this to remote repo,

```
git push --all --force
```

but that doesnot get pushed successfully,It tries till the last and suddenly comes as the remote repo is not reachable or not responding of that sort

I also tried rewritting the tags

```
git filter-branch -f \ --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch node_modules' \  --tag-name-filter 'cat' -- --all
```

I also tried the following to make it work

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory 0
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit 0
git config --global pack.threads "3"
```

But whatever I do the size of the repo is still the same

Note: I tried

```
git fsck --full --unreachable
```

There are several tags listed that are not reachable

Comment: Only commits that *cannot* be accessed - except by hash - are pruned (ie. check the repo again with git log and path). Also, were the files of significant size to notice?

Comment: Yeah,I checked with git log -- node_modules, I get no output. Actually the files are not that much significant size, but there are several that the node_modules folder is about 30MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mention in [Git pull error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685422/6309) that git gc alone isn't enough.

One combination which should bring down the size of the repo should be:

```
git gc
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

However, This must follow any cleanup of big file ([`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)), and that is only for the local repo.

After pushing (`git push --force`) to the remote repo, said remote repo won't benefit from the same size reduction. A gc/repack/prune needs to be done on the remote side as well.

And [if that remote side is TFS... this isn't easy/possible to do for now](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1019193/unable-to-clean-a-git-repo-in-tfs).

Comment: I am unable to repack "Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack-36a49c503c404065dd29b6802740456aac25fa2f.
pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y" is the message I get

Comment: Actually the size has increased now

Comment: @keerthee do you have another proces using that file? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6076796/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/25138946/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10181965/6309)

Comment: I saw that link. But I dont think that file is being used. I will close applications and try repack again

Comment: I get the same thing again, I tried to get the handle using the pack object form process explorer, the process owning that is git-upload-pack.exe, but I am unable to kill this process

Comment: @keerthee try and reboot, if possible

Comment: VonC, I tried the repack and prune, yet it is still the same size

Comment: No luck, it is still the same size

Comment: @keerthee What would happen if, after that gc-repack and prune, you try to clone locally that repo? Would the clone be smaller?

Comment: All the above operations are made in the local repo only, it has already been cloned from remote, also not pushed to the remote repo. The thing is the local repo is itself the same size

Comment: @keerthee I understand that. I am asking: what if you clone the local repo where you did the git-repack and prune: would the local clone of the local repo be smaller then?

Comment: I tried doing it. but looks like it is cloning the remote repo $ git clone --local file:///C:/Users/<user>/Documents/SourceCode
warning: --local is ignored
Cloning into 'Code'...
warning: no threads support, ignoring pack.threads
remote: Counting objects: 6906, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3112/3112), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (6906/6906), 5.88 GiB | 8.84 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 6906 (delta 4011), reused 6127 (delta 3647)
Resolving deltas: 100% (4011/4011), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (1428/1428), done.

Comment: @keerthee don't use the `--local` option or `file:///`: if your repo is in folder `a`, what happen if you clone it in `b`? `git clone a b`.

Comment: I tried it, but still the size remains the same $ git clone SourceCode SCCopy 
Cloning into 'SCCopy'...
done.
Checking out files: 100% (1428/1428), done.

Comment: @keerthee when you select "Properties" on the destination folder, the size is still 6GB+? If that is the case, I can only assume the `git filter-branch` didn't work correctly.

Comment: Yeah thats the case, one thing I missed out to say, I have cloned only one branch (master) to the local repo, still there are branches in remote, Will that cause any issues

Comment: @keerthee no, that shouldn't affect the filter branch, the gc-repack-prune or the clone. I would double-check if the filter-branch worked or not.

Comment: One more thing, I find lots of unreachable commits and blobs listing when I run git fsck --full --unreachable

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry folks!!!
In addition to node_module there was another main culprit ntvs_analysis.dat that caused the huge size of the repo. Now I have removed that and now the repo size is 75 MB. Even the steps that I have followed itself was working

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. +1. I still think my answer can help ;)

Comment: I have got one more problem. Now the cloud size remains the same, even I did git push --all --force

Comment: I would recommend the gc/repack/prune sequence on the bare repo on the cloud then.

Comment: Is bare repo a necessary thing, I have the cloned version of the cloud repo in local,I dont have a bare repo in local

Comment: @VonC Looks like the deleted file still exists in remote git,I cloned the remote repo to another folder,there the .ntvs_analysis.dat still exists with same size. Are there anyways to make sure the rewritten commits are pushed properly to remote

Comment: That is why I mentioned in my previous comment "on the cloud" (when you clone locally, the repo is generally not bare, and that is ok). Did you do a `git push --force` after removing the big files from the history?

Comment: Then you need to contact the remote server admins for them to do a gc/repac/prune on the bare repo server side.

Comment: OMG... Okay https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1019193/unable-to-clean-a-git-repo-in-tfs Looks like TFS doesnt have such feature

Comment: I have got one more problem now, I created a new repo and pushed the cleaned repo there,but only master branch was available there.So I cloned the old repo again to get other branches.The size is still the same,but when I try to do the above cleanup there are no changes, the size remains same

Comment: From the old repo, could you push all branches (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4886153/6309) to your new remote repo?

Comment: Actually I deleted the cleaned local repo and now clone the old repo and trying to clean it up,But neither of the above steps works out

Comment: Yes, but maybe pushing all branches will not make the remote repo bloated. Try to backup the remote repo first, and then try and push all branches, to see if the size is too big.

Comment: Actually in the local  git is itself,it is big

Comment: You could try and push branch by branch, to see the effect on the siez on the remote repo.

Comment: Hi,VonC,Actually I guess I havent described my problem properly. I deleted the cleaned repo from local.Now I have cloned the old repo from the remote again.Its size is now as bigger as before(6GB) in local too.I try to clean it up now (i.e) delete the file with huge size,it doesnt exist now (as I deleted previously itself and pushed to the old remote repo).So those files are somewhere in the git.I dont know how to delete it