# Bitbucket: git push error: pack-objects died of signal 13

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

I tried to push my local repo to my origin branch on Bitbucket, and kept failing to push it. The error shows like below.

```
Counting objects: 2309, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Compressing objects: 100% (2295/2295), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to ....
```

I already tried

```
git config http.postBuffer 5242880
```

and the result showed the same error. I also tried to change my setting from https to ssh, but still there was the same error.

I guess it may be because I push large files to my remote repository. I have not requested any updates for one month, and only done pull requests to update my local repo.

Comment: Any chance can try the same push using a SSH remote URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you already raised the http buffer size, this might still be related to the general size of your repo.

[This thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/11981675/push-fails-with-error-pack-objects-died-of-signal-13) mentions:

> This repo is well in excess of our size limits. We don't store repositories of this size. We do not offer that as an option to any of our commercial plans, either. 1GiB/2GiB is a firm and inflexible limit for everyone.
>
> As much as we want to offer larger repos, the performance of repos over 750MiB or so is too bad to tolerate. We hope you understand this limitation.
>
> To check this I was asked to run:

```
git count-objects -Hv
```

(See "[Find size of git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16163608/6309)")

That would explain why switching to ssh does not constitute a workaround in this case.

Comment: what is the solution for this issue ?

Comment: @John reduce the repository size (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31309715/6309)