# How can I remove all files larger than some given size from all my unpushed Git commits?

Tags: git

How can I remove all files larger than X MB from all my unpushed Git commits?

Comment: Do an interactive rebase (and edit all newer commits), iterate through all files, test if the are bigger than X MB and remove them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history

Comment: Sorry for this poor experience. I am always grateful for moderator, but your question, specifically on unpushed commit, was just fine.

Comment: There are at this point 4 "reopen"s; one more should do it. Note that the existing "remove large files" questions-and-answers are generally the right ones, the only constraint you've added is "unpushed commits". For one particular branch `foo`, the range-restriction `origin/foo..foo` should do the trick with `--filter-branch` or `filter-repo`.

Comment: @VonC and unsurprisingly my previous comment got removed...

Comment: I had to delete repo, git init again and follow this answer in similar situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To purge the history of the repository, you might consider the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M --refs master~3..master
```

Replace 3 by the number of unpushed commits you have (FYI: [view unpushed Git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2016901/395857)).

Or:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M --refs origin/master..master
```

Note if you get the error message `Error: need a version of git whose diff-tree command has the --combined-all-paths option` when running the above-mentioned commands, it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).