# Remove folder from a git repo not working - repo size issue

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I am trying to remove a folder from my git repo .
reason being I am getting space issue error `remote: repository is in read only mode (over 2 GB size limit). ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

The folder on the repo is about 1.32gb

I have followed these questions - [How to remove a directory from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-from-git-repository) & [Removing unwanted folders from git repo permanently - Repo size not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308515/removing-unwanted-folders-from-git-repo-permanently-repo-size-not-changing)

But still getting the same error.

Any one help?

Comment: did you tried [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner) ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`filter-branch` present in "Removing unwanted folders from git repo permanently"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31308515/6309)  would only remove certain files. Other might still be important.
As commented, [**BFG**](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner) would help removing *all* files past a certain size from the history of the repo.

```
git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
cd some-big-repo.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Then you would to to a `git push --force --mirror` in order to push all the rewritten branches.