# Why my .git is always bigger when I just write a few code?

Tags: git, macos, .git-folder

This happen twice: I already erased my repo, because of a filesize too big (>100mb), then it always failed when get test in CI/CD GitLab.

So i create the new repo, ... and it happens again: when I check my folder size, the main problem is `.git`: I dont know what happen and I don't know the solution.
I just have 2 branch (`master` and `develop`), and several commits (because it is a new repo)

Then I keep searching the solution , with git command:

```
git gc --aggresive --prune=now
```

but still `.git` pack so huge, so I really need your help to find this solution, because I don't want to erase my repo again and the problem came again
my new repo (so bigg)

gitlab repo information:
[image: gitlab repo information]

whatsize folder:
[image: whatsize folder]

Comment: Can you post your .gitignore please? And is snitch a binary file?

Comment: It seems there are binaries in snitch and vendor. If the binaries are added and committed, .git gets big as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, make sure your **[`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)** will ignore any generated binary.

Try first to remove anty big files from your past commits, with [BFG Repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) ( faster than the native [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch))

```
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 2M some-big-repo.git
```

Only then you can apply [git gc/repack/prune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31309715/6309) in order for the size to actually go down.

```
git gc
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```