# Git: “Corrupt loose object” even on new clone

Tags: git, terminal, linux-mint, corrupt

Before starting I would like to tell that this may look like a duplicate question, but I have try those all & still facing the issue.

**Now my issue is**:

I was working in a local git branch suddenly the power went OFF & System turned OFF. Later, when power is back, I tried to pull my branch & it shown a message as:

```
../bug_11677 $ git pull
error: object file ./objects/3f/5774584d2f00d4adf0a82b5e2be0feee5c894a is empty
error: object file ./objects/3f/5774584d2f00d4adf0a82b5e2be0feee5c894a is empty
fatal: loose object 3f5774584d2f00d4adf0a82b5e2be0feee5c894a (stored in ./objects/3f/5774584d2f00d4adf0a82b5e2be0feee5c894a) is corrupt
```

**I have tried:**

1. Remove git index & tried to reset by keeping the changes in file:

   `git reset --keep`
2. Tried by removing git object folder:

   `find .git/objects/ -type f -empty | xargs rm`

   `git fetch -p`

   `git fsck --full`
3. Tried one as below:

   `rm -f .git/objects/3f/5774584d2f00d4adf0a82b5e2be0feee5c894a`

   `git fsck --full`

When I tried the last one, it shown:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (342770/342770), done.
Checking connectivity: 342315, done.
```

Later I pulled the branch, then again I got the corrupted message.

4. I have *also tried to clone* my branch newly, but failed by same error.

**I have gone through below links:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32194011/4229270
- [Git: "Corrupt loose object"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4254389/4229270)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749070/4229270

Answer (score 0):

> I was working in a local git branch suddenly the power went OFF & System turned OFF

That is a local event, meaning you were not in a middle of a push, meaning no impact to the remote repo.

A downgraded solution would be to clone the repo again, and report your current modification to the branch. Then push.
That might mean a slight loss of history on that branch.

If however, the issue persists during a *clone*, then the power outage did not affect just your workstation, but also the Git hosting repositories *server*.

The [OP Sinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4229270/sinto) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569615/git-corrupt-loose-object-even-on-new-clone/53576124?noredirect=1#comment94082816_53576124):

> I have called server tech & checked the issue.
>   He said that was Git files where corrupted in server and it is fixed now from the server side.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I was not able to clone the same branch. Same issue was there on clone the same branch. There I failed actually.

Comment: @Sinto Even after a fresh new clone of the remote repo? What I don't understand is: you dod not push anything at the time of the outage, so a new clone should be possible.

Comment: I'm was not able push anything after this issue.. but still the error showing there. Same happened when I tried to pull my other git branchs which was not in use at the power failure time.

Comment: And what happen if you pull push from a new locally cloned repo?

Comment: In both(pull, push or clone) case it show same error. No problem now, because I have called server tech & checked the issue. He said that was git files where corrupted in server & it is fixed now from the server side. And now I'm creating my branches in git & merging it with the backup file what I have in my local.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @Sinto Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.