# Lost git commit after rebase & force push - post git object removal

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I ran the below command to fix the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571557/fixing-a-corrupt-loose-object-as-a-commit-in-git) issue:

```
find .git/objects/bd/4e31f16fc91fdc25b4b8e50c16c6f12422d467 -size 0 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

After that when I **force pushed** my code after rebasing & squashing older commit, everything is lost and pull request got closed automatically erasing all commits. There is no way I can get back my code from whatever I know. **The commits have vanished.**

**Is there any way to get back my committed code?**

Comment: Does someone else had same commits? Do you have disk backups? Have you tried disk recovery tools on .git folder?

Comment: @MotiKorets No it was my branch. I am trying to get the files from IDE history.

Comment: Try disk recovery tool for .git repository looks like its the only chance..

Answer (score 1):

> pull request got closed automatically erasing all commits

If this pull request is done on GitHub, then [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) would still be able to restore those commits, erased by the forced push.

Through the GitHub API, you can even yourself [query the past push events, performing a "poor man reflog"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309).

But regarding local commits, check first your **[`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)**.