# Remove git corrupt blob from repository

Tags: git, corrupt

I have a situation with a corrupt object in a repository.

```
$ git push
...
fatal: loose object 95b6a826cadae849f4932a71d6735ab6ceb47cab (stored in .git/objects/95/b6a826cadae849f4932a71d6735ab6ceb47cab) is corrupt
...
```

And I know that this objet is a blob linked to by an old commit:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from  tree 27e8e7d5b94c1dad5410a8204089828a167a0eaf
            to    blob 95b6a826cadae849f4932a71d6735ab6ceb47cab
```

I have done the [classic steps to recover the blob from the FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#fix-broken-repo) but it seems there is no other copy of it anywhere that I can find (I am working alone and haven't push to the remote for a while so it's not there) so I can't recover it.

This blob is actually the first version of a file which has been modified a lot since then. I am fine losing the information about that version of the file. So I would like just to remove it from the commit that is pointing to it. How can I do that?

Comment: Try looking at some of the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4254389/1031900

Comment: This question is about a corrupted tree, which is a bit different. None of these answers can help me, sadly. I am going to try a few things and will post it here if they work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured it out myself eventually.

Short version: I amended the commit pointing to the corrupt blob to remove it from the history.

Long version: I thought that since I knew what the file was, and just wanted to make it disappear from the commit, then I could just amend the old commit. I didn't really expect it to work, but eventually it did.

I have to point out that I removed the blob in .git/objects in trying previous things, and it is possibly important into why it worked.

First, i had to know what commit it was. For that I used the command

```
git log --raw --all --full-history -- subdir/my-file
```

I found the commit was named 966a46....

Then I did the steps to amend it. Since it was an old commit, I used

```
git rebase -- interactive 966a46^
```

My editor came in with one line for each commit, and I changed "pick" to "edit" in front of the commit I wanted to modify.

The command `git status` showed me that the file I wanted to erase was modified:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   subdir/my-file
```

I wanted to remove it from the commit, so I did `rm subdir/my-file`. `git status` then showed me:

```
#       deleted:    subdir/my-file
```

This looked promising. So I simply committed the amended commit and continued the rebase:

```
git commit --all --amend
git rebase --continue
```

But after having rebased a few commits it failed with this error:

```
error: could not apply 45c2315... did some fancy things
fatal: unable to read 95b6a826cadae849f4932a71d6735ab6ceb47cab
```

45c2315 was the first commit in which my file was modified after having been created. Since it didn't find the previous version of the file, it just failed.

`git status`showed me, among other things:

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       deleted by us:      subdir/my-file
```

I'm actually not sure what it means, but this commit was supposed to be the first in which the file would appear, after the fix. So I didn't want it to be deleted, but on the contrary, added to the commit! So I did

```
git add subdir/my-file
```

And surely `git status` showed it as a "new file".

Then I did `git rebase --continue` and everything went good, and the rebase was a success.

`git push` went then smoothly instead of failing about the broken blob.

But there were still a problem, because `git fsck` was still failing:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 27e8e7d5b94c1dad5410a8204089828a167a0eaf
              to    blob 95b6a826cadae849f4932a71d6735ab6ceb47cab
```

And `git gc` failed too, when I asked him to prune everything. So I figured out the best course of action was, since I had successfully pushed before, to clone everything back in a new repository and work from there.