# git status shows fatal: bad object HEAD

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with git on Windows Azure. Git status shows - "fatal: bad object HEAD" and I tried running:

```
 git fsck --full
 git gc
```

But  `git fsck` shows:

```
broken link from  commit 739df633f185ce5d1ab7eb97d619b28e7d81185a
              to    tree 2a6d4876d135c1fa7cbe1348c62570006e895fc5
broken link from  commit 9c7eae5ffed34dbfac977e515dee675626b59f93
              to    tree 400132d215ab9aced883a9971e648b82624b2032
broken link from  commit 9c7eae5ffed34dbfac977e515dee675626b59f93
              to  commit 4a49af0a0cb64a0a0415734b11772d6df18561fb
broken link from  commit bc3072f30e71c616a8196089e19a67a2c9c0a5ad
              to    tree 0aa813c183487d0a1b1f7ae81501ca7a1168283f
broken link from  commit d3bb4f8545e91ec8ace15ad31a3147d92a1d4242
              to    tree 4682108accd8e72fe68858232386dffe60f9f02d
broken link from  commit 6b34795c4b54286301bcdc0ed254a04c132cb2ad
              to    tree 5c57dd3222d11924dba841d3cae517bdc9220601
broken link from  commit d70172d855391b93bc1c5eeb9b4226df525dfc6e
              to  commit 390c8cbd527c8e707c51e25142e54421f4dd3948
broken link from  commit cc05e8d2e3733693ebb67d697ae4b65e51fea79a
              to  commit 32f081f8b901425fd1e8898478f0551970bee0f5
broken link from    tree 6a75ed6d0311d800078e77f43d427d128372d5bc
              to    blob 4a064d610c0e7207967d59934c8bc5f491f26dae
broken link from    tree 6a75ed6d0311d800078e77f43d427d128372d5bc
              to    tree 5c06ec964dcbade49287d0f36efe1f7b60f446e3
broken link from    tree b4855fa6734b5652a93a9b799eafe47fad0d13a0
              to    blob 3e1fb421613dc9066cbf9c95eddc61619a9f8eed
broken link from    tree b4855fa6734b5652a93a9b799eafe47fad0d13a0
              to    tree 556a50048d42346c283c94b78ea278ba1d57d251
broken link from    tree 289c03409370c4ca7c12266ce2822a2976bd032b
              to    blob 3abf3c48ada45f63404dcf4d675ddfdadcfa83c6
broken link from    tree 289c03409370c4ca7c12266ce2822a2976bd032b
              to    blob 3fa569892003b468ed1301426dd6d96d9644be3c
broken link from    tree 289c03409370c4ca7c12266ce2822a2976bd032b
              to    blob 0a9a54a51e84f3bc34122dbce1146d895fcbe22c
broken link from    tree 289c03409370c4ca7c12266ce2822a2976bd032b
              to    blob 3fa48873564361b4d95830803ae77f79eeafaf5b
```

`git branch` shows - *master

Comment: Looks like the repository's broken on filesystem level. To restore HEAD you write something meaningful to `.git/HEAD`, like `739df633f185ce5d1ab7eb97d619b28e7d81185a` or `ref: refs/heads/master` (if `master` branch is OK) . But it's unlikely to fix the repository.

Comment: I don't think HEAD itself is broken, but rather the thing it ultimately points to.

Comment: I had the same error - but `git fsck` already fixed it for me. Thanks 

Comment: this happened to me when i create a patch file with `diff` and forgot to ignore the `.git` directories.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your repository is corrupt. That means data is lost that cannot be recovered by git itself. If you have another clone of this repository, you can recover the objects from there, or make a new clone.

`fatal: bad object HEAD` means the branch referenced from HEAD is pointing to a bad commit object, which can mean it's missing or corrupt.

From the output of `git fsck`, you can see there are a few tree, blob and commit objects missing.

Note that using git itself is not enough to keep data safe. You still need to back it up in cases of corruption.

Comment: This worked for me, I clone repository to another directory then just delete corrupted .git folder and replace it with .git from clone. then running git init, git fetch and git status will auto detect the last uncommitted changes

Answer (score 105):

try this; it worked for me (**Warning: this destroys work that exists only in your local repo**):

***`rm -rf .git`***

You can use `mv` instead of `rm` if you don't want to lose your stashed commits

then copy **.git** from other clone

***`cp <pathofotherrepository>/.git . -r`***

then do

***`git init`***

this should solve your problem ,  *ALL THE BEST*

Comment: I was looking for a tricky git command but after all, this one is quick and clean enough.

Comment: It works! Thanks! But there is a warning... you will lose all the things that are not in your working directory (local branches, stash, etc). Maybe you want to use `mv` instead `rm -rf` to try to recover something latter ;-)

Comment: @FernandoAlmeida Yeah thats right , if you really want to recover , you can just use `mv` instaed of `rm` , thanks buddy :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. While Ikke gives very good information this is the fix dotnetrocks was looking for...

Comment: Beautifully worked like a charm: superb. 
A couple final commands if anyone interested, specifically for me, were:

git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories | git checkout --ours [yourmainfolder]/ (or --theirs: accept remote versions. --ours accept local versions) | git status | git add --all | git status | git commit -m "First commit after git corrupt files" | git push origin master > Thank you very much, great, great solution :))

Comment: do you realise that with `rm -rf .git` you will lose all your stashes and branches that you did not push to a remote yet.

Comment: I just had this after migrating to new PC. I simply did `pull` from gihub (although there was nothing to pull) and then commit/push. using `sourcetree`

Comment: Maybe edit @FernandoAlmeida's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264032/git-status-shows-fatal-bad-object-head#comment84309734_45730454) of using `mv` instead of `rm`, or at least the warning of what can happen if you don't, into the post itself?

Comment: Worked for me,  You save me lot of work

Answer (score 69):

This happened because by mistake I removed some core file of GIT. Try this its worked for me.

re-initialize git

```
git init
```

fetch data from remote

```
git fetch
```

Now check all your changes and git status by

```
git status
```

Comment: I had to upgrade git (homebrew) when getting a segfault. After `git fetch`, I had to do a `git pull` to fast-forward (it says my tree is behind HEAD), before `git status` could show me anything useful.

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall git gue to some issue. after that sourcetree stopped working. This solution worked for me

Comment: I first got a different error - "Corrupt loose object". Whatever the error was, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098509/2005759) followed by your answer fixed it without losing anything or re-cloning.

Answer (score 38):

Running

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

followed by

```
git gc
```

Comment: This! My origin had it's primary branch renamed from `master` to `main`. This answer solved the issue.

Comment: Add `git fetch`, then `git merge origin/HEAD` then `git push` worked for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me without needing to do the destructive operations suggested in the higher rated answers! Nice work.

Answer (score 34):

In my case the error came out of nowhere, but didn't let me push to the remote branch.

```
git fetch origin
```

**And that solved it.**

I agree this may not solve the issue for everyone, but before trying a more complex approach give it a shot at this one, nothing to loose.

Comment: I often get this error after partial file syncing between computers. This fixes it everytime for me.

Comment: I'm also confused and pissed how file syncing works, I've had troubles like this with Dropbox and with Megasync. This .git dir is supposed to be sync with two nodes

 `du -s .git` on client1 is `4.2M`  and `3.8M` on client2

I don't know why or how sync clients manage to skip files in .git dir...

Comment: I am encountering this problem frequently. I could not identify why this happening. But this answer saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Your repository is broken. But you can probably fix it AND keep your edits:

1. Back up first: `cp your_repository your_repositry_bak`
2. Clone the broken repository (still works): `git clone your_repository your_repository_clone`
3. Replace the broken .git folder with the one from the clone: `rm -rf your_repository/.git && cp your_repository_clone/.git your_repository/ -r`
4. Delete clone & backup (if everything is fine): `rm -r your_repository_*`

Comment: This answer just brings together the goods of [@serup's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25607163/1870254) and [@ganesh's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730454/1870254).

Comment: Best workaround if somehow your existing repo is broken! But be cautious, it would remove your stashes unfortunately. Though it fixes the head!

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem and what worked for me was to make a new clone from my original repository

Comment: I ended up here after a Windows 10 crash whilst using VS2017(15.3.3) and git.  I didn't have any pending changes, so using @serup 's answer above, specifically I: 
- removed the root solution folder "C:\Code\MySolution" (that contained .git as a subfolder).  
- then from VSTS | Project=MySolution | Code | master branch page, I clicked "Clone" button and chose "Clone in Visual Studio"
- I entered the same location "C:\Code\MySolution".  

All very simple (in the end).

Comment: That means you lose local branches, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix a similar problem to this when some of git's files were corrupted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30871926/1737957

In my answer on that question, look for the part where I had the same error message as here:

```
fatal: bad object HEAD.
```

You could try following what I did from that point on. Make sure to back up the whole folder first.

Of course, your repository might be corrupted in a completely different way, and what I did won't solve your problem. But it might give you some ideas! Git internals seem like magic, but it's really just a bunch of files which can be edited, moved, deleted the same as any others. Once you have a good idea of what they do and how they fit together you have a good chance of success.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this happened because of a bad commit object.

For example,

```
ubuntu@server41:~/proj31$ git status -s | grep M
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

I had to copy the .git directory from the newly cloned in another directory(same repo) to the git repo that had this problem. (see below)

```
ubuntu@server41:~/proj31$ cd ..
ubuntu@server41:~$ mkdir newr
ubuntu@server41:~$ cd newr
ubuntu@server41:~/newr$ git clone https://github.com/account434/proj31.git
ubuntu@server41:~/newr$ cd
ubuntu@server41:~/newr$ cd proj31

# copy .git directory from newly clone(same repo) to the one which has this problem.

ubuntu@server41:~/proj31$ cp -r ../newr/proj31/.git .
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing git fetch. My error was because I moved my file from my main storage to my secondary storage on windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

I had the problem where I had local changes preventing me from checking out the main branch, `git status` would give me `fatal: bad object HEAD`, and `git stash` would give me `BUG: diff-lib.c:607: run_diff_index must be passed exactly one tree`.

#### Solution

I found that I probably was on a pruned branch (I believe). Force checking out the main branch and then deleting that branch did the trick for me:

1. `git checkout main -f`
2. `git branch -D <name_of_branch>`

**Note**: I did do some juggling with a backup of my `.git`-folder, re-cloning the original repository somewhere else, and overwriting the `.git` folder temporarily to try to restore git functionality, but in the end the commands above was what saved me with my git history intact!

Comment: Best answer ever `git checkout main -f` just saved me a full branch

Answer (score 2):

Clone the repository to another directory then just delete corrupted .git folder and replace it with .git from clone. then running git init, git fetch and git status will auto detect the last uncommitted changes

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by looking at the commits from `.git/logs/HEAD`, then copying the last hash, and replacing it in `.git/refs/heads/BRANCHNAME` (where `BRANCHNAME` is for example `main` or `master`).

Then I had to commit the changes of that last commit (they were staged already) and *I think* I fixed the repo. My repo didn't have any remotes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @jan-glx should always work. I am adding here step 3., which is needed in case you were working on a branch other than master/main:

1. Back up first: `cp your_repository your_repositry_bak`
2. Clone the broken repository: `git clone your_repository your_repository_clone`
3. (if needed) Switch to your working branch in the cloned repo `cd your_repository_clone && git checkout your_working_branch`
4. Replace the broken .git folder with the one from the clone: `rm -rf your_repository/.git && cp your_repository_clone/.git your_repository/ -r`
5. (if everything is fine) Delete clone & backup: `rm -r your_repository_*`

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your git dir in your local host and run `git init` there once again. Push the project to a brand new reprository.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by copying the branch data (with the errors) to my apple laptop local git folder.

Somehow in the terminal and when running:  git status, tells me more specific data where the error occurs. If you look under the errors, hopefully you see a list of folders with error. In my case GIT showed the folder which was responsible for the error. Deleting that folder and commiting the branche, I succeeded. git status was working again
the other devices updating by git pull; everything working again on every machine.

Hopefully this will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be the source of your problem - but if you happen to be working in .NET you'll end up with a bunch of `obj/` folders. Sometimes it is helpful to delete all of these `obj/` folders in order to resolve a pesky build issue.

I received the same `fatal: bad object HEAD` on my current branch (master) and was unable to run `git status` or to checkout any other branch (I always got an `error refs/remote/[branch] does not point to a valid object`).

If you want to delete all of your `obj` folders, don't get lazy and allow `.git/objects` into the mix. That folder is where all of the actual contents of your git commits go.

After being close to giving up I decided to look at which files were in my recycle bin, and there it was. Restored the file and my local repository was like new.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a old simple project without branches. I made a lot of changes and when I was done, I couldn't commit.
Nothing above worked so I ended up with:

1. Copied all the code with my latest changes to a Backup-folder.
2. Git clone to download the latest working code along with the working .git folder.
3. Copied my code with latest changes from the backup and replaced the cloned code (not the .git folder).
4. git add and commit works again and I have all my recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried cloning from the remote repository to a new TEST local repository. Then used the new .git folder to replace the "corrupt" .git folder. Ran **git status** and could see the latest differences.

[image]

BEWARE: Check differences between your local folder and repo using **git add . -v**. To undo changes before commit use **git reset**. You may need to bring "deleted" files from the TEST local repository cloned in the beginning of this operation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when I used submodules

## The file structure

```
-- Python.Hot
-----.git/
-----Python.OpticalTweezers/
-----Python.OpticalTweezersGUI/
-----.gitmodules
```

## Question

when I checked the log of any submodule, I came across this issue.The waring message is "**Could not open log. libgit reports:bad object xxxxxxx**"

This issue doesn't exist in the several versions at the very beginning.

## snapshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: `git fsck --full` and `git gc` seems to work. This issue disappears in the following commits after I used these two commands.(The issue still exists in the commits before this operation)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a backup of my local files with mv dir_with_issue dir_with_issue_bkup

From there I cloned the repo again and ran cp -r dir_with_issue/.git dir_with_issue_bkup/.git

This fixed the issue and I kept my local changes

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by renaming the branch in the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.

Comment: To what and from what?

Answer (score -2):

The error "bad tree object HEAD" in Git typically occurs when there is a problem with the repository's object database, which is where Git stores all of the objects in the repository.

You can run this command in your terminal : **git fsck --full**
then you can run the command **git status**

This worked fine in mine case. you can also try.