# Git status shows "fatal: bad object HEAD"

Tags: git, git-status, git-fsck

I have just done a `git status` and it's throwing the following error:

> fatal: bad object HEAD

I have also tried `git fsck` which gives the following output:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 921078fd0d6521b5f12f1c46dc9865c2856e9dc0
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
notice: No default references
missing blob 247d4de31a5b4b32c075c3249ae581a735dadc23
```

Any ideas how this can be easily fixed?

Comment: git reset --hard <some known ref>

Comment: Also I think you should re-fetch from a remote repo, if you have one. If no, then likely you've lost some of your changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git status shows fatal: bad object HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264032/git-status-shows-fatal-bad-object-head)