# Git cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference HEAD

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, sourcetree

I'm trying to commit the changes to my repository but I receive the error below:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F C:\Users\Contronym\AppData\Local\Temp\bkdweixb.mnu
fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference HEAD: Invalid argument

Completed with errors, see above.
```

I'm using bitbucket and SourceTree.

What's the reason for this commit failing? I was able to commit just fine the last 3 commits over the past week. Then, all of a sudden, I receive this error.

**EDIT**

I ran `git gc` and these are the results:

```
$ git gc
error: bad ref for HEAD
error: bad ref for HEAD
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 53b65bd9b4fec7f6a7b0b3313c68199a18804327 (stored in .git/objects/53/b65bd9b4fec7f6a7b0b3313c68199a18804327) is corrupt
error: failed to run repack
```

I checked the directory `.git/objects/53/b65bd9b4fec7f6a7b0b3313c68199a18804327` but that doesn't exist. There's two other files there, but `b65bd9b4fec7f6a7b0b3313c68199a18804327` doesn't exist.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I ran it. Can you check my edit?

Comment: Try `git fsck --full` now. Also go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/20264177/1190388

Comment: may be you have lost the HEAD. Recreate it using `echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD`

Comment: or use `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master` for newer version of github

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only solution that I found was to navigate to the head like so:

```
.git/refs/heads/branch_name
```

And I deleted the head file. Then I went to the console and I used the command:

```sh
git reset
```

Then all the files were unstaged so add them and commit them afterwards.

Comment: Only deleting `.git/refs/heads/branch_name` solved my problem, thanks a lot

Comment: this works for me. But the problem now is that it's going to break the chain that connects to the remote repository. therefore you might encounter another error trying to push to the remote, though that can be configured too

Comment: there's a better way to do this... See this comment and apologies for the down vote:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929220/3165947

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

Step 1.

- go to `.git\logs\refs\heads` and open the Document named as `YOUR_BRANCH`,  now copy  the `ID` numbers in front of your user name and email

Step 2.

- go to `.git\refs\heads` and open the document named as `YOUR_BRANCH`  delete the line and paste the `ID` in.

Answer (score 13):

1. Navigate to directory `.git/refs/heads/branch_name`
2. Delete the preferred branch name
3. Open terminal(git bash or cmd for windows)

   ```bash
   git reset
   ```
4. Commit the changes (if necessary)
5. Run the following command for merging the remote repository branch

   ```bash
   git pull
   ```

   If it gives related to refusing to merge unrelated histories, run the following command in the terminal:

   ```bash
   git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me, into terminal enter: (branch accordingly to your desires lul)

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after calling git commands with the root user inside the working copy. So the owner and owner group of various files under .git/ were changed to "root".

When I switched back to my user account, git could not handle this files anymore, because of the lacking permissions.

It worked again, after resetting the permissions with

```
sudo chown -R [MY_USER]:[MY_GROUP] .git
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I used this command:

```sh
git reset
```

Answer (score 2):

check branch name 
git show-ref --head

Firstly, just checked the error, here you will find which reference is broken

Step 1: just remove this mentioned reference
rm .git/refs/heads/branch_name

Step 2: git fetch
Step 3: git pull

Will work 100% sure....

Answer (score 1):

When I run into this I just git clone the project into a new file directory and pull the heads folder from located at `.git\refs\heads` and replace the original heads file in the directory that your having the problem. Then just delete the new clone you created (since it obviously doesn't have the updates your trying to push).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file `.git/ORIG_HEAD` then pull again. For me the `.git/ORIG_HEAD` file was 0 bytes and has `.lock` extension instead of the git reference it was supposed to contain, so I just got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You want a quick, 100% working solution ?

I tried a few of the ones suggested here (thanks Guys !), but to no fixing the case for me.

1. rename your directory with _old.

2.git clone your project again, into a brand new directory.

Then , move your files one by one / resume your work.

That's garanteed to work ! - even if playing with git commands looked funnier in the beginning. :)

Note: the spacetime between the "git clone" command and your files will lay on your files only, so beware if you're in the case of several commits and no push done : the commits list (and logic) will be lost.

Comment: thats what i did too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed my issue:

```sh
rm -rf .git/refs/heads/
```

Comment: Extremely dangerous if you don't know what you're doing -- this will remove *all* branches from your repository and potentially cause you to lose track of a large number of commits (which will later be deleted if you don't fix it soon).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, today.
I found a very easy workaround to this problem but has a few trade-offs.
I am still not sure what caused it in the first place.
I came across a lot of solutions, and unfortunately, nothing really worked for me.

I could not initialize a GitHub repo during this error, which actually helped me find a solution.
Apparently, just deleting the .git directory solves a lot of issues. Just when I deleted that directory, I was able to initialize a repo.
You shall find the .git folder in your workspace.
.git(dir)/config(file) . the config file may be broken and could be the source of the issue. (I am not sure of the cause, any explanations in laymen would be much appreciated)

just when I deleted the folder, all the errors vanished. I was also able to commit from GitHub desktop (which was throwing me the error, previously, the same error while committing directly from the IDE)

The only downside to this would be, all your staged changes might be lost, that is only it. And you may have to initialize a new repo because giving the same name would throw error(if the same repo already exists)

So, apart from that, you shall be good to go. You can commit changes too now.

Comment: The only trade-off is : all your prev. commits will be lost.

Comment: But, all the changes in files will be tracked, no issues. Just the commit message will be the one you initially commit after initializing a repo, to dodge the error, For me, no commands worked, but this one worked fine. So, if you too are having trouble, follow this one , if commands dont work...

Comment: TL;DR => delete the .git folder/initilaize a repo with a new name, that doesn't already exist in your Github

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your `.git` folder
2. 

```sh
git init
git remote add origin url
git commit -m 'msg'
git push origin dev
```

Comment: You should warn people about what happens when deleting the .git folder, no? I mean what if there's a long history on the repository? You know it will all be lost, right?

Answer (score 0):

remove the head.lock file then retry

```
rm -rf .git/HEAD.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the user and group managing your project.

```
ls -las
```

[image]

Then add permissions

```
sudo chown -R -c username:group .git/
```

[image]

I hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:

1/You need to remove all local heads store on your machine

->Remove  .git/refs/heads/

->Remove  .git/refs/remotes/origin/

2/Go to gitub and copy the id of your last commit
[image: Get id of the last commit]

3/Use the following command to reset your project on the last commit:

`git reset --hard <last commit id on image above>`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

There's an even easier way to address this outside of having to reset your local repo / etc.

Within the `.git` folder is a specific file you should be looking for and there is another within your `.git/refs/heads` directory you should have as well.

Do you see `HEAD.lock` in `.git/`?   Delete it or rename it to something like `Head.lock.save` if you're paranoid.

Do you see a `{branch_name}.lock` file in `.git/refs/heads` too?  `{branch_name}` should be the name of the repo branch you are actively trying to commit to.  Delete / rename it too.

Now retry your commit and you should be good to go.  There is no need to wipe out entire directories and reset your local repo to recover from this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me when I encountered this error.

> error: update_ref failed for ref 'ORIG_HEAD': cannot lock ref
> 'ORIG_HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'ORIG_HEAD': reference broken

```
rm -rf .git/ORIG_HEAD
git reset
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I just used command:

```
git reset
```

Then I removed file `/my_project_directory/./git/refs/heads/master`
and then I can use this command:

```
git reset --hard <my_hash_of_last_commit_on_remote_branch>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind **losing your history**, you can delete the `.git` file and then:

```
git init
```

This will reinitialize your repository and you can then proceed from there.

Answer (score -1):

Clone the project again, install modules and checkout to your branch. It will be restore the state.

Comment: Yes you can, but `git reset` is more efficient