# Git error 'Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind' after reset

Tags: git

I'm using git GUI on windows, and I ran into errors about git not finding reference for HEAD. So I deleted the current branch from the git repository, and ran the `git reset` command (as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057962/git-cannot-lock-ref-head-unable-to-resolve-reference-head)).
Now when I try to push my code to a remove repository (which, as far as I know, shouldn't have changed at all since I last pushed), I get an error saying `that the tip of [my] current branch is behind`.
I absolutely don't want to pull or merge anything from the remote repository. I just want to push my local code to remote.
How can I do that ?

Comment: You can't push if your behind your repo head. Unless you specify --force option, but be mindful on what you're doing.

Comment: Which precise `git reset` command did you use ? To check remote has not changed, you should run `git fetch` and then better `gitk -15` to see what is going on.

Comment: Please see, this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes

Comment: You could stash your changes if you didn't commit them, doing merge then re-apply them.