# Git Cannot lock ref 'HEAD'

Tags: git

I made some commits yesterday but didn't push them. Today I woke up I tried to push it and I had

> error: bad index file sha1 signature
>   fatal: index file corrupt

I tried to:

```
$ del .git\index
$ git reset
```

and  then tried to push my commits once again but it fail and now I have

> fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/light-mode': reference broken

What's going on? I don't want to lose my commits but more important I don't want to lose my local changes into project.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1115854/5784831?

Comment: There's no info about this ref 'HEAD'. I deleted .git/index and run git reset but I still got error I don't know what to do I think I'll need to create new repo and push my local changes but I'll lose my commits history branches pull requests etc...

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39057962/5784831? There are some good suggestions for analysis. Perhaps this helps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Git repository has been damaged.  It's not possible to say *by what* or *by whom* at this point.  A common culprit is using Dropbox or similar to store the `.git` directory.<sup>1</sup>  A less-common culprit is actual hardware failure, e.g., your spinning-rust disk or SSD is failing.

This message:

> ```
> fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference
> 'refs/heads/light-mode': reference broken
> ```

occurs because your current branch, `light-mode`, has its hash ID stored in either `.git/packed-refs` or `.git/refs/heads/light-mode`.  One or both of these files either contains garbage, or no longer contains the hash ID of a valid commit.  Again it's not really possible to guess which files have which specific problems, nor what programs or hardware failures caused them.  The work you did *may* have been damaged or destroyed irretrievably.

If you know the *correct* hash ID of the commit you made yesterday, you can attempt to recover that hash ID using, e.g., `git checkout hash`.  If all else fails, you can run `git fsck --lost-found`: for each hash ID for which Git prints *dangling commit* or *dangling blob*, Git also saves the *contents* of that commit or file into `.git/fsck/lost-found`: look at the `commits` and `other` folders.  The `other` folder will contain the found files' data.  The *names* of those files are no longer available, but you might recognize some important content and therefore be able to say: *aha, that's the important file I wanted back* and get it back that way.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a very bad idea in general, because Dropbox and Git fight over who will control specific files' specific contents.  It *can* work for a while, leading to a false sense of security.  Then—usually right before an important presentation or a class deadline or whatever—*boom*, Dropbox decides that six critical Git files should be rolled back to some previous version, and your work is gone.

Comment: I don't use dropbox and my SSD seems to be working fine, that's mysterious

Comment: Can you tell why this error occurs automatically ?  I didn't do anything , was working yesterday and now doesn't.

Comment: @BadriPaudel: no, it requires manual investigation and/or situational knowledge (e.g., "oh, the power dropped out yesterday and the system had to reboot and ate a few files when it did that" or "the administrator moved everything from one disk drive to  another yesterday" or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to Dropbox as possible cause. I just had this problem with a git repository inside OneDrive. When viewing the content of .git with the Windows explorer it says: "Location is not available - [...]\.git\refs is not accessible. The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid."

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience and for me the issue is that I use Git Bash as well the inbuilt Visual Studio Git plugin.

What worked for he was deleting the branch file in the following location
.git/refs/heads/branch_name

Then I went back to Git bash and executed the following command `git reset` and I was good to go.

Lesson for me I think is, going forward I will use Git Bash all the way.

Comment: Do you mean if you use integrated terminal in IDE instead of git bash, it may create problem ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 git remote set-head origin --auto
```

> Sets the default branch (i.e. the target of the symbolic-ref refs/remotes//HEAD) for the named remote. Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch. For example, if the default branch for origin is set to master, then origin may be specified wherever you would normally specify

:)

Comment: you should add what it does

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing in linux you can remove the index (make a backup copy if you want), and then restore index to version in the last commit

rm -f .git/index

git reset

Comment: Hello. That's exacly what I did but on windows machine. Please read my question.

Comment: git fsck --full

Comment: Man please... If I remember correctly if I run fsck I can lose my local changes

Comment: if still you are getting same error make a backup copy and reset git repo
git reset --hard head

git clean -f

git pull

git checkout branchname