# fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create 'G:/folder/.git/HEAD.lock': File exists

Tags: git

I accidentally stopped an ongoing git commit and later when I try to

```
git commit -m"xyz"
```

I get the following message

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create 'G:/folder/.git/HEAD.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

I tried following the suggestions given here [Git cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057962/git-cannot-lock-ref-head-unable-to-resolve-reference-head) and tried

```
 rm -rf .git/refs/heads/
```

Unfortunately, this didn't help and I still get the same error message posted above when I try git commit.

I also tried git reset and this also gives the same message displayed above.

Alternate suggestions on how to resolve this issue will be really helpful.

Comment: Whoa, `rm -rf .git/refs/heads/` basically destroys your repository! If it did not, you either did not have any commits, or have just cloned the repository, or you have just completed a `git gc`.

Comment: @j6t I didn't clone the repo. May I know how to check if my repository isn't/is destroyed?

Comment: Why not remove the lock file?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried rm -rf HEAD.lock in  .git.  Post this when I try again to commit , I see `741 files changed, 2764175 insertions(+), 3954 deletions(-)` . I definitely didn't make these many changes after what I had committed and pushed yesterday.  I am not sure if this is because I did `git reset` a while ago. So is it safe to push my changes?

Comment: What you see *may* be a result of that you blew away your branches with `rm -rf .git/refs/heads/`. You basically destroyed all your commits since you pushed the last time. In your current state, **do not push**, or **all** your commits are gone!!

Comment: Serious debugging is necessary to salvage as much of your work as possible. As a first step, make a backup copy of your working directory, including what you still have in the `.git` directory before you do any further experiments. At this point, consult an expert near you that looks over your shoulder.

Comment: There's still a trace of where the refs were (name and last active commit) under `.git/log`

Comment: I downvoted and left a comment on the answer that suggested `rm -rf .git/refs/heads` in the post OP linked. Not a great look.

Comment: @LeGEC: It's `.git/logs` with an *s*, at least on my machine. I got curious and tried whacking a repo this way myself, and `git reflog` doesn't work with the repository in this state, so good to know.

Comment: please define "stopped an ongoing commit". How?

Comment: @DaemonPainter I did a ctrl + C

Answer (score 2):

[this is an answer to "How do I revert `rm -rf .git/refs/heads`"]

You can restore your branches by reading the branch names and last active commit straight from the log files :

```sh
find .git/logs/refs/heads -type f | while read log; do
  ref=$(echo $log | sed -e 's,logs/,,')
  mkdir -p $(dirname $ref)
  echo $(tail -1 $log | cut -d' ' -f2) > $ref
done
```

Run the above on a linux-ey system with `bash`, or in `git-bash` on Windows.

---

Step by step :

- git stores the evolution of each branch / reference in a file, under `.git/logs`. The first command lists those files for branches (refs starting with `refs/heads`) :

```
$ find .git/logs/refs/heads -type f
.git/logs/refs/heads/master
.git/logs/refs/heads/foobar
.git/logs/refs/heads/baz/2
.git/logs/refs/heads/baz/1
```

You can look at the content of any of these files :

```
$ cat .git/logs/refs/heads/baz/2
0000000... 219145b... Legec <some@email.com> 1603086835 +0200   branch: Created from master
219145b... 425bc45... Legec <some@email.com> 1603086837 +0200   commit: d.txt
425bc45... 84324a8... Legec <some@email.com> 1603087374 +0200   commit: e.txt
84324a8... 5c2e4de... Legec <some@email.com> 1603087380 +0200   rebase (finish): refs/heads/baz/2 onto cbe105c...
```

each line stores "that ref moved from xxx to yyy", with a message describing what triggered this evolution (commit, rebase, reset ...)

This is the file from which `git reflog that/branch` reads its info.

- to get the path to the actual ref, you just need to ditch the `logs/` part from this path :

  ```
  ref=$(echo $log | sed -e 's,logs/,,')
  ```
- suppose your branch is named `thats/my/branch/name`, you need to recreate a directory at `.git/refs/heads/thats/my/branch/` before creating file `name` in it :

  ```
  mkdir -p $(dirname $ref)
  ```
- finally : from the last line of the log file (`tail -1 $log`) extract the second field (`cut -d ' ' -f2`) and store that in the approriate ref file :

  ```
  echo $(tail -1 $log | cut -d' ' -f2) > $ref
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply navigate to your local repository in the cloned directory and  look for .git folder, indise .git you will see the lock file. JUST DELETE it. and you are done.