# Git cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference HEAD when i try to commit

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with Github.
Yesterday it was working normally, but today it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

i clicked the button to stash it but doesn't take me anywhere. I opened vscode, so, look the error file
[image]

so I pasted and copied the code saved on Github web, ok, I saved it, I tried to make a commit end it's error.
[image]

i don't know what i should do for my github to work normally

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: Please post console output as text, not as images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057962/git-cannot-lock-ref-head-unable-to-resolve-reference-head)

Comment: This is a secondary problem, but you need a `.gitignore` so that git ignores the node_modules folder. You could use this one: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Node.gitignore

Comment: @tymtam thanks for help me, and sorry about the images!
I managed to solve the problem, but I had to do a git reset --hard "in the project folder" and clone the repository again

Answer (score 0):

Run `git fsck` and post the output.

If that shows errors (and I'm pretty sure it will), try running:

```bash
git reflog expire \
    --stale-fix \
    --expire-unreachable=now \
    --all \
    --rewrite &&
for REMOTE in $(git remote); do
    git remote set-head "$REMOTE" --delete
done
```

Failing that, try a re-clone.