# error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD[Conflict]

Tags: git

Git is running very slowly and it seems it's because of some corruption in the commits. I can push, pull, I can add commits, do whatever I like -- but it's extremely slow and I want to have this fixed. `git fsck --full` gives this output:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (594/594), done.
error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD[Conflict]
dangling blob 8878936a624d253188a7d3fb6826127ed4ef5559
dangling tree 3ffae6058ee5efdbf19b4bce8121a13269b03efd
dangling commit 6f8bcab8772694419ebd1e05c91b4dfdbc2e00d0
dangling blob 02ecfc281060f70d07001f78fe52b563bbe8c7cf
dangling blob a2a462441865b7a5e93b122cc8198a4aad24f8d3
dangling blob 05cf7cb901a50715d12aee741afcd348f1508d58
```

I've also run `git gc` and it didn't really fix anything.

I have a lot of files in the directory though that are intentionally not in the repo but which I wish to keep. All commits have been pushed already into the remote repo. What's the best way to get rid of the `bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD[Conflict]` problem?

Comment: What operating system are you running on?  Are you using a third-party antivirus, firewall, or monitoring software?  Are you running the repository out of a directory that's managed by a cloud syncing service?

Comment: I'm on Windows. I was able to solve it finally, and will post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it this way similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60838427/3198568):

1. Used `git clone` to get the files from the remote repo into a *new* local folder (say, `/remote_backup`.
2. Checked out the branch that should be identical to the local copy (important!)
3. Created a new folder `/local_new`.
4. Copied all the files from the original folder to `/local_new` except for the `.git` folder.
5. Copied the `.git` folder from `/remote_backup` into `/local_new`.
6. `git init` in `/local_new`