# Git: bad Object HEAD

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I got stuck cause I forgot to put a message to a commit. So, since i did not how to exit the `vim` (or whatever) I just got into the .git folder and deleted every file in there.

The thing is that now I get this message:

```
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

and if I use the `git fsck` this:

```
error: refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer 92921ef183ebb792a66213ecfd31fa0a4dc32685
error: refs/original/refs/heads/master: invalid sha1 pointer 58c2fbc2fa2645100f45c919cbda6b5bea3f44c3
error: refs/remotes/origin/master: invalid sha1 pointer 92921ef183ebb792a66213ecfd31fa0a4dc32685
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 92921ef183ebb792a66213ecfd31fa0a4dc32685
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry 92921ef183ebb792a66213ecfd31fa0a4dc32685
notice: No default references
```

Finally, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264032/git-status-shows-fatal-bad-object-head) and got this:

```
Move-Item : No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del parámetro 'rf'.
+ mv -rf .git
+    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

*No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del parámetro*

means something like:

*Can't find any parameter that matches with the name of the parameter 'rf'*

and same happens with 'mv'.

PD:I know that I shouldn't have deleted everything just like that. But now I don't know how to keep working.

Comment: "I know that I shouldn't have deleted everything just like that" Indeed. You destroyed your repo and now you wonder why things are not working? Basically at this point all is lost. Delete the _.git_ folder entirely; it is worse than useless.

Comment: I really don't care about the repo, I got the files I need in a folder in my pc. And I can't delete the .git folder, there is another folder inside that cannot be deleted.
And I am not wondering why things are not working. I now why that is. I am wondering how to make them work again.

Comment: What does "work again" mean? Without the repo there is nothing for Git to do. And you destroyed the repo. So there is nothing to "work".

Answer (score 0):

Deleted files inside the `.git` folder?! Really???

I suggest you do a fresh `git clone` because I don't think that's going to be fixed magically with whatever command you try.

To exit `vim` (the best editor ever), you use:

```
ZZ
```

or

```
:wq
```

when you want to write and exit, or:

```
:q!
```

When you want to exit without saving. In this case, git does nothing.

Another solution, in case you end up in another weird editor...

```
mv .git safe-git
```

Kill that editor in some way... and then

```
mv safe-git .git
```

Because if the `.git` folder disappear, nothing is going to happen... (I would be surprised that `git commit` or such keep files open while you are editing; but even if that's the case, blowing your editor away by killing the process should have the same effect as quitting the editor without adding a message and thus aborting the commit).

Comment: Thank you, I found that information. The thing is that i closed the console with the ```vim``` thing. So I could not do another action cause that vim thing was "still running".

Comment: @JuanIgnacioMelo Ah. That could be a lock issue... I think that git creates a lock when you do a commit so two people (including yourself in another console) can't attempt that command simultaneously.