# git server error: corrupt loose object on remote

Tags: git, server, git-pull, git-clone, git-fsck

I have an error in response to 
`git fsck --full` 
which is `corrupt loose object '...'` 
on a git server machine.
I don't have a local repository. I can't clone. I don't have the object in repo/objects/...

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?
The object is not inside the repo.git/objects directory. 
I can ssh inside the server machine.

any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT

I've tried with

```
git gc --prune
```

but i'm receiving the same error

`error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance code)
error: corrupt loose object '4e4c................'
fatal: object 4e4c............. is corrupted
error: failed to run repack`

EDIT 2

`git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

gives me the same error
and also

`git gc --aggressive --prune=all`

With

`git ls-tree 4e4cc....`

I have the same error

EDIT 3

I've found a local repo(of 10GB) with the last commit and I can push to the remote (of 20GB). I can also pull from that local. Why they are different in size? I still can't clone... and the obj 4e4c............. is not inside .git/objects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem. Git stores an object like 4e4cfe... creating a directory 4e (ex.repo/objects/4e/) and putting the object 4cf3... inside that directory. I was searching for the object 4e4cfe... and, of course, I couldn't find it. However the object was corrupted but I had found a good one (after git fsck --full -v) inside a local repository and I just copied it in the remote repository. So at the end to resolve the problem you need a simple "copy and paste".

Answer (score 0):

I think its a corrupt object. Although it is slow, you can try this code:

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

There is also a documentation written by Linus Torvalds about similar errors and reconstructing the blobs : [click here.](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt?id=HEAD)

Comment: It gives me the same error. I've read the article but it is not this case.

Comment: There are similar posts, chek this and see if it helps,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object

Comment: I've already read that answer and honestly it doesn't help, and the link Scott Chacon's Git Screencasts doesn't work. How can I "infer the structure of the tree object from those objects"(cit)? I don't have the object in .git/objects/..