# Github error while trying to push

Tags: git, inflate, data-stream

So I have commit all my local changes successfully, but then when I try to use `git push`, it gives me the following error message:

> Error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method) fatal:
>   loose object a92cbc6c3f5f7e44614ec2ce2a4f29475fcc0766 (stored in
>   .git/objects/a9/2cbc6c3f5f7e44614ec2ce2a4f29475fcc0766) is corrupt
>   fatal: The remote  end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung
>   up unexpectedly fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor

I don't know what happened because git has been working fine when I was in my previous projects.  Can anybody shed some light on this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some files got corrupted and you will need to do a git clone again. Or, if you wanna be more specific, you can get problematic file from one of your colleagues that owns one (that is intact). However, you will lose commit history that way, if it is of much importance to you.

If you haven't come across this answer chain - I strongly recommend it - your error message appears there :

[Git: "Corrupt loose object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)