# repo sync error: object file is empty

Tags: android, linux, git, android-source, repo

I'm trying to sync Android from a git repository but I continue to get the following errors:

```
error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider.git/objects/3e/182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4 is empty
error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider.git/objects/3e/182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4 is empty
fatal: loose object 3e182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4 (stored in /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider.git/objects/3e/182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/developers/samples/android.git/objects/54/1590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986 is empty
error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/developers/samples/android.git/objects/54/1590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986 is empty
fatal: loose object 541590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986 (stored in /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/developers/samples/android.git/objects/54/1590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: refs/remotes/aosp/master does not point to a valid object!
error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider.git/objects/3e/182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4 is empty
error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider.git/objects/3e/182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4 is empty
fatal: loose object 3e182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4 (stored in /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider.git/objects/3e/182f346bd88df9de1082714c9d0fe0886571f4) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/developers/samples/android.git/objects/54/1590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986 is empty
error: object file /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/developers/samples/android.git/objects/54/1590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986 is empty
fatal: loose object 541590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986 (stored in /home/build/android-7-docker/android7/.repo/projects/developers/samples/android.git/objects/54/1590183e5d796cc3c4a40fad185ea23efd9986) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Cannot fetch platform/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider
Fetching projects platform/external/libutf/
Fetching projects: 14% (74/522) error: Cannot fetch platform/developers/samples/android

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

How can I fix this? Any ideas to how proceed in this particular case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: "Corrupt loose object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)

Comment: This looks like that your repo is corrupted. You can try to run `git fsck` in this repo. The best is to throw it away and clone it again.