# fatal: loose object happens too often with git only in Ubuntu VM

Tags: git, virtual-machine

When I work with git on Windows 10 I never get this problem. But when I work with git in Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox it happens pretty often and it is really annoying. I know there is an answer for that, but is there any long term fix for that so it doesn't happen at all?

I have tried initializing another git repo and then pushing it to that new repo but that doesn't work.

It says something like this:

```
error: object file .git/objects/cf/... is empty
error: object file .git/objects/cf/... is empty
fatal: loose object ... (stored in .git/object/cf/...) is corrupt
```

I expect it to commit changes when I do `git add .` and `git commit -m "foo"`. But it gives that error pretty often.

Comment: You might be interested in the second answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object

Comment: If you're using a VirtualBox "shared folder", stop. Use a private-to-the-VM (pseudo) disk. Shared folders just don't work reliably.

Comment: There it is. I was thinking forced shutdowns and filesystems configured to assume some power-out protection, but shared folder seems much more likely.

Comment: @torek can you give me some links on how to do that please?

Comment: I don't use Windows but when I set up a VM on MacOS, the VM has some shared folders and some private ones. I just make sure I put all my "real work" repositories in the private ones. I do have a few in shared folders but I don't work in them as they flake out.

Comment: @torek i am not using shared folders in my VM, but I am still facing this issue.

Comment: @LukaPavicic did you find the cause for the issue