# Why do Git files/objects become corrupted?

Tags: git

I am new to Git and have been using it for a few weeks now on my Ubuntu Virtual Box Machine. Usually, I would run my git commands in the Visual Studio Code terminal. I have encountered the following errors a few times already whenever I start a new session on my virtual machine. 
`error: object file ... is empty` 
`fatal: loose object ... is empty`

The solution provided by cubic lettuce [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object/13918515#13918515) managed to solve the issue. Out of curiosity, why does this happen? Is there something that I should avoid doing to prevent my local git repo from being corrupted?

Thanks! :)

Comment: git crashes, or is terminated, at an inopportune moment, or your virtual machine does the same, or you turn off power at some bad time when data is written. Under normal circumstances, git does not corrupt repositories.

Comment: Also, keeping a git repository in certain places such as a shared drive (Google Drive, DropBox, etc.) can cause it to be corrupted.

Comment: A bug in the filesystem driver, a bug in the kernel, a bug in the system libraries, a bug in VirtualBox, a bug in Git, a bug in Visual Studio Code, a hardware problem with your disk, your disk controller, your RAM, your CPU, a bug in some backup script or a cleanup script, a power failure / brownout, the same virtual disk accidentally mounted to two VMs, …