# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, repository

I got the following when I try to git push to heroku

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I try to follow ruby on rail tutorial book.

I think I installed the client heroku package(by downloading from heroku website and follow their instruction to install, GUI format installation). So my client side heroku should be ok (I am new to programming , so not sure if saying by this term is correct or not).

Then I open a new terminal and key in

```
git push heroku master
```

I got

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Can anyone good at this explain which part I missed? i.e. have to move to some directory first?

Please show me the command since I might still have no idea without command.

PS: I think I have repository in my github already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receiving "fatal: Not a git repository" when attempting to remote add a git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo)

Comment: Not a duplicate of it.

Comment: Hello; I get the same error trying to acquire DebugKit for CakePHP. I'd like to amplify the question by asking WHY do I need to be IN a repository when, as I understand the instructions, I am attempting to DOWNLOAD FROM a repository? In other words, all I want is the content so I can use it. But ... if it is NECESSARY to create a repository in order to acquire the contents, WHY DON'T THE INSTRUCTIONS SAY THIS? Not all of us are familiar with "git" you know!

Comment: UncaAlby you want `git clone <path to repo>` but before the comment stack overlords see this, you may want to make this a question somewhere else. People will answer it.I'm sure there is an easy git workflow for beginners question somewhere.

Answer (score 17):

You aren't on a git repository directory.

Yype `pwd` and make sure it's where you think you should be. Chances are you are in `~/` or something just before the directory you think you are in.
Or maybe you are in C:/ drive instead of the one you are. To change your directory from drive c to d use this command `cd D:/` then figure out your files with this command `ls`.

Comment: Either that, or the original poster never initialized a repository in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

Have you created a git repository? Create it using `git init` and then commit some files.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Answer (score 5):

update sep 2020

first, you have git repo required to create a heroku app

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

how your code uploading to Heroku

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have followed all the steps in the [Installation and setup](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec-git_setup) section of the Rails Tutorial book.

The error message you are getting is indicating that you have missed the `git init` step.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you mean to do `git clone` but instead do `git checkout`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, this happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to encounter this error despite being within a git repository.

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114649/3753318 has it exactly right:

> In my case a system crash had caused the HEAD file to become corrupted. This guide shows how to fix that and other problems you may encounter.
>
> https://git.seveas.net/repairing-and-recovering-broken-git-repositories.html

If the .git/HEAD file is messed up in some way, this will also lead to the "not a git repository error"

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you are trying to push the changes from a non-cloned working copy of your git repository. have you initialized git repo on the dir that you are working?? if not so initialize git repo by using `git init` and then either do a `git clone` or add a remote by using `git remote add origin git@github.com:repourl.git` for more detail refer [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone)

Answer (score 0):

If you previously had an initial commit from local to GitHub remote, or if you previously pulled from remote to local, then you have set up your remote. What worked for me is signing into my remote GitHub repo, and then this error went away and able to push/pull changes from local to remote, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This error will happen with `gh`, the Github CLI client, if you run a command like `gh pr list` outside of any Git repo. Instead, use a command that doesn't need to be run in a particular repo, like `gh search prs`.