# Git Clone Repo Has No .git File

Tags: git, git-init

I cloned a repo with `git clone <path to repo>` but when I run `git status` I get the `fatal: not a git repository` error.

What I want to know is, if I run `git init` in the local directory that was cloned, will it screw anything up or cause issues with the initial repo on GitHub?

I `cd && ls -a` into a few directories but I don't see the `.git` file.

So I first did a search with `$ git ls-files | grep .git` and got the same `fatal no repo` error.

Then I did a search with `$ find . | grep .git` and it listed 3 `.gitignore` files. Which I assume means the initial creator didn't initialize git.

I want to create a branch and begin working and making commits without messing up the original repo.

I've referenced these following StackOverflow questions but they don't give me the answer I need:

["fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)" from git status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961600/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-from-git-status)

[fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888972/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git)

Comment: Is what you're trying to clone an actual repo then?  On the remote box, if you change into that directory, what does `git status` give you?

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but, did you actually `cd` into the directory after cloning before typing `git status`?

Comment: @SébastienDawans Not a stupid question. Yes I did.

Comment: @Makoto Not sure I follow. The original directory is on GitHub. Is it possible to run `git status` on that repo remotely?

Comment: No (except if you have access to the shell at the Github servers, which would only be the case, if you're working there as an admin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your repository seems to be broken. Make sure that you didn't erased by error the `.git` folder after cloning. Maybe, just clone again and work from that new clone.

Comment: I deleted the repo and cloned it again like you suggested but this time I used the GitHub GUI app. Then I `cd && ls -a` into the directory and the `.git` file shows up. Thanks @MatthieuPizenberg

Comment: Confirmed that using GitHub Desktop app to do the clone instead of clone from CLI worked to restore the .git file (thanks Frank). Cloning from CLI results in no local .git repo. Seems like a bug, not sure why cloning one way would be different than another. I'm on MacOS 10.11 El Cap, GitHub Desktop 222, git CLI version 2.9.3 (Apple Git-75).

Answer (score 2):

I think .git file might be hidden.

To fix this go to "Folder Options" then press "show hidden files, folders and drives".

Then do not forget to navigate into the folder where .git resides.

This may fix it, if I got your problem right.

Cheers.