# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git

When I tried to push an existing repository on github.com, and it when I entered the command the website prompted me to put into the terminal, I got this error message                 fatal:

```
Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

If anyone could help me with this, then that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are CD'd into a git repository directory or subdirectory in your terminal?

Comment: This can also happen if you exported your `CDPATH` environment variable, and one of the sub-directories of a repo happens to be named same as another non-repo-subdir under one of the paths in your `CDPATH`. Sounds crazy, but that wasted hours of my time recently before solving it.

Comment: similiar solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/git-receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git

Comment: You need to be in the directory that holds the repo, it typically has the '.gitignore' file.

Comment: If you previously had an initial commit from local to GitHub remote, or if you previously pulled from remote to local, then you have set up your remote. What worked for me is signing into my remote GitHub repo, and then this error went away and able to push/pull changes from local to remote, and vice versa.

Answer (score 821):

The command has to be entered in the directory of the repository. The error is complaining that your current directory isn't a git repo

1. Are you in the right directory? Does typing `ls` show the right files?
2. Have you initialized the repository yet? Typed `git init`? ([git-init documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))

Either of those would cause your error.

Comment: I got this error when I opened the gitshell and typed the command -->  git remote add origin https://github.com/ascenttech/Hst.git  
Any suggestions

Comment: I just wanted to add that the error appears even if we are in the correct directory and the repository has been initialized, in case we accidentally delete or pamper with the .git folder.

Comment: I had not done 

"git init"

it resolved

Comment: @Freya: that seems to be the case for me, since `.git` exists and all. What do you suggest is the best way to solve this problem in that situation?

Comment: In my case I had changed by mistake the permissions of the files in .git

Comment: I had .gitignore and just rename it _.gitignore in rails app

Comment: I was getting this error and it turned out to be the permissions set on the .git directory itself.  Was 660 .. updated to 770 and everything worked fine.

Comment: My .git-folder was in the recycle-bin , lol

Comment: Using ```cd path\of\your\repository``` in Windows before running the command fixed it for me

Comment: I had to run `sudo -R chmod 770 <PROJECT_DIR>`, then it worked for me

Comment: Most of the time it is because you have not initialized your repository with git init

Comment: This should be marked as right answer.

Comment: It could be a permission issue.