# how to use Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

i am comfortable using Github to but i am trying to migrate to bitbucket since it supports private repositories by default.

My reason is because to make a repository private in Github, you have to pay some fee, but bitbucket.org provides it for free. I just created an empty repository named testproject, and i'm trying to push my files from my system to 
 the repository online,

this is what i am trying to do ..

```
git clone https://ande_EAD@bitbucket.org/ande_proj/testproject.git

cd testproject
echo "# My project's README" >> README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

all my git-commands are giving this error ::

```
"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"
```

please can someone assist me, whats the proper way of adding content to your repository on bitbucket.  and note :: i prefer using command line than any software except otherwise.

if this works then i can successfully push other projects online, and invite the teams to join me.

Comment: What did the `git clone` command say?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen good point, did the clone even create the repo folder locally? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are in the correct folder?

See this answer:

[fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413459/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git)

When I use Bitbucket I tend to do things the other way round, i.e.:

- Create my git repo locally using `git init`
- Add and commit any files
- Go into bitbucket and create a new repository
- Then switch back to git and run:

`git remote add origin https://<user_name>@bitbucket.org/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git`

`git push -u origin master`

Comment: @Andaeiii if you do it the other way round local repo -> BitBucket it will def work, I do it all the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) destop app to handle your repos in bitbucket and other services

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i prefer using command line, maybe i should update the question,

Comment: did you tried to move to the parent dir before you commit and push?