# fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)

Tags: git, directory

I get the said error when I run the code `git status /path/to/file` or like `git add "/path/to/file/README"`

I've initialized the `/path/to/file` using `init` `git init /path/to/file`. This seems to work fine

From git manual `git status [<options>...] [--] [<pathspec>...]` I understand this means I can add `/path/to/file` (also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715321/git-status-is-there-a-way-to-show-changes-only-in-a-specific-directory)) or did I get it wrong?

Tried the answers [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413459/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git) and also the links (under **This question already has an answer here:**) in it.

`git clone url /path/to/file` works fine but `git status /path/to/clone/` gives the same error

Tried Uninstalling and re-installing git. `git` version is 2.14.1 running on Ubuntu 17.10

Edit: If I `cd /path/to/file` and run `git status`, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `git status`, it was very useful to debug the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git needs to know where the repository is, running `git status /path/to/dir` is not enough. Either the current directory is a (sub)directory of a repository (that is, `cd /path/to/dir`) or you explicitly say where the repository is:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/dir/.git --work-tree=/path/to/dir status README
```

or

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/dir/.git WORK_TREE=/path/to/dir git status README
```

Seems like `cd` is the shortest and simplest solution.

Comment: Is it `--work-tree`? (that's what `man git` gives me; `Unknown option: --work-dir=` error displayed). Also `git -C /path/to/dir/ <command>` works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `git -C "path_to_dir" <command>` worked perfectly! As a side note, putting the path in double quotes allows paths with spaces to be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same issue, I wasn't in the same directory as the project (since after cloning it, you have to `cd` into it).