# Personal toolbar button in Forge Viewer not appearing

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, viewer, forge

I followed the tutorial to learn Autodesk Forge. I linked my BIM 360 account to the Forge Viewer. I would now like to add extensions to it and have a button on the toolbar that links to my extensions.

However when I follow the extension tutorial, nothing shows up. I also tried this one https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/tutorials/toolbar-button/#before-you-begin and nothing appear.

I do not know what I am doing wrong since it seems to work if we follow the tutorial...

I am working on VS code

Right now, my code looks like this in the index.html file : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc9uC.png)

The rest is exactly like the tutorial except that I replaced "MyAwesomeExtension" with "PieChartExtension"

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try will be to switch your var config3d to the following:

```
var config3d = {extensions: ['PieChartExtension']}
```

The reason might be, your syntax might be affecting and that is why the Viewer does not understand what to load. Did you check the console for any messaging?

Comment: My output console gives me this 
 git rev-parse --show-toplevel
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I made the change but it does not change anything, I still don't have another toolbar button...

Comment: another thing I see is your extension is specified to be in "/js/" and all your other js files are in "js/" that forward slash might be causing the project confusion and not being able to find it. The git error seems related to not being part of your git repo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413459/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git

Comment: Still nothing... I checked the entire code again and compared it to the tutorial. I really do not know where the problem is ...

Comment: I got it ! I did the tutorial again from the start and it works this time. Thank you for you help !