# git CMD Not Showing All Branches

Tags: git

I am extremely new to git.

I am using Git CMD.

When I type `git clone ....` I am able to clone the repository successfully, but when I type `git branch -a`, it doesn't give me a list of all branches available.

What am I doing wrong?

My end goal is to use `git cmd` to switch branches.

This is what happens:

> c:\users\username\projects>git branch -a
>
> fatal: not a git repository(or ay of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Even though you've done a clone ..  Have you done a full git fetch remote?  Can you check out the branch that's "not there" ?

Comment: It looks to me that you're not in the project directory ..  Like you should be in `c:\users\username\projects\my-project`

Comment: I'm going to need to see what git fetch does. One sec.

Comment: When I moved to the name of my project and typed git branch -a, it gave me a list of all of my branches. That's the solution to my problem. Thank you for helping a n00b out.

Comment: Yup. Git clone doesn't (can't) switch your shell into the cloned directory, it's one of those way-too-susceptible-to-abuse features that's just never going to happen. cd in after cloning.

Comment: As written, I think your question is misleading when you say "not showing **all** branches", and also "it doesn't give me a list of **all** branches available". It's not showing **any** branches because you weren't inside of a repo.

Comment: I think if you had asked your question based on the error message, then it would be a dup... Does this answer your question? [fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413459/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is installed on a "per project" basis.  So each project will have it's OWN `GIT` repository.  You need to be sure you are in the project directory you want to be in, and then issue your `git` commands IE:

```
c:\> cd c:\users\username\projects
c:\users\username\projects> cd my-project
c:\users\username\projects\my-project> git branch -a
```