# Git won't show log unless I am in the project directory

Tags: git

I am trying to call `git log` while I'm in a different directory. I pass the location where the `.git` is

```
git log /Users/Leica/proj1
```

but it says "not a git repo". If I `cd` into this directory, it works fine

```
cd /Users/Leica/Proj1
git log
```

Which is not clear to me. The [`git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) says

> ```
> git log [[--] <path>…]
> ```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Git commands generally won't work unless you use them from within a project directory that's tracked by Git.

Comment: Related: [Receiving “fatal: Not a git repository” when attempting to remote add a Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4630704/456814).

Comment: Then I wonder why the docs mention the path for the log command... Or did I misunderstood the path option in the log function in Git?

Comment: That's for file paths ***in the repository***, not the path for the repository itself.

Comment: gah; so I misunderstood the option parameter; my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how git works. It wants to be run from inside the working copy (does not have to be at its root).

If you really must do this (but why?), you could do

```
$ git --git-dir=/Users/Leica/proj1/.git log
```

The "path" option of the log command refers to file paths *within the repository* (rooted at the repository root, not your file system root). It limits the output of the log to commits relevant to those files.

Comment: I see; it was not clear to me why it won't accept the command, and at this point I wonder why the log doc has the path as option, if you can't use it straight away. Thanks!

Comment: `(but why?)` Because I'm in a shell script?

Comment: I guess you are right, I was trying to find a corner case but I don't have one. _Touché_. :) Someone might argue that you should be careful to `cd -` afterwards. But again it's a script, one should be careful anyway. Thanks for adding that piece of information anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Git needs a repository on which to operate, as demonstrated by [Thilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076234/456814). Thus, there are three ways you can tell Git where to find the repository:

1. The `--git-dir=<repoPath>` flag, as Thilo answered.
2. The `GIT_DIR` environment variable.
3. `cd` into the project directory that contains the repository directory `.git`.

According to the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html), `GIT_DIR` is set to look for a `.git` directory (in the current working directory?) by default:

> If the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is set then it specifies a path to use instead of the default `.git` for the base of the repository. The `--git-dir` command-line option also sets this value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my assumption was that you could pass a path to the git repo itself; hence I misunderstood how to use correctly the option and its parameter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Git log's path option is only for filtering directories in a git repository.
For example

```
cd /Users/Leica/Proj1
git log ChildDirectory
```

will give you log only about `Proj1/ChildDirectory` so if there is a commit in Proj1 directory what doesn't affect on ChildDirectory it won't appear.

If you want to use git from a different directory, you need to pass `--git-dir=<pathToRepository>` option.