# not valid: is this a git repository?

Tags: git, github, clone, gerrit, gitblit

My question is NOT [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo) question. 
On performing a `git clone` I am getting this error. Command than I am using is:

```
$ git clone "https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/?r=mytest.git&h=refs/heads/branch_development"
```

On simply running:

```
$ git clone "https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/?r=mytest.git"
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir '?r=mytest'.: Invalid argument
```

I think I need to put the full URL along with r and h parameters. Because these parameters specify the name of my repository.

I was doing a mistake (copying and pasting the URL). However, even on using the URL:

```
gdt.test.com/gitblit/r/mytest.git/
```

I am getting error:

```
'fatal: repository 'gdt.test.com/gitblit/r/mytest.git/'; not found.
```

How to copy correct URL from gitblit summary page?

Comment: I can clone it just fine. Btw how is this related to gerrit?

Comment: But does your local directory have a git folder?

Comment: @Vaulstein: Yes my local directory has a .git folder. First I performed 'git init'.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: But how can you clone a git URL that does not terminate with .git?

Comment: @QualtarDemix Are you sure you want to `init` and then `clone`? The usual way is *either* `init` then `remote add` *or just* `clone`.

Comment: @Biffen: I performed git init to simply create a .git folder. But in future i'll take care.

Comment: @QualtarDemix `clone` will do that for you. Also, `init` will create a `.git` directory *in the current directory*, whereas `clone` will clone into a subdirectory in which the `.git` directory will be created (unless otherwise specified).

Comment: @QualtarDemix Looks like it's having trouble creating a directory based on the last part of the URL. Have you tried specifying one, e.g. `git clone "https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/?r=mytest.git" mytest`?

Comment: @Biffen: On running "https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/?r=mytest.git" I am getting a new error: fatal: could not create work tree dir '?r=mytest'.: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem. I was using the wrong git repository altogether. Correct URL must be:

```
git clone https://qualtar.demix@gdt.test.com/gerrit/mytest
```

Answer (score 7):

Problem: you are copying & pasting the log webpage URL and expecting to be able to clone a repository from the generated html.

The proposed successful answer has sufficiently scrubbed the URL which hides the solution from you: you are missing the repository serving path in the URL,  `/r/` or `/git/`.

Using your URL example, the correct syntax should be:

`git clone https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/r/mytest.git`

The Summary page provides generated URLs with copy & paste functions to avoid these type of errors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply. And yes I was doing the exact same mistake (copying and pasting the URL). However, even on using the URL that you suggested I am getting error: 'fatal: repository 'https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/r/mytest.git/' not found.
Also, can you please put a larger screenshot to explain how to copy URL from gitblit summary page.

Comment: The attached screenshot is enough.  Do you see the little clipboard buttons?  They are flash.  They will copy the url to your clipboard for pasting.

Answer (score 0):

The url is not the path to a git repository BUT yes mytest.git is a bare repository

Edit: Try this and it works at my end

```
git clone https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/mytest.git

git clone "https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/mytest.git"
Cloning into 'mytest'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Comment: On running this command I am getting:
fatal: could not create work tree dir '?r=mytest'.: Invalid argument
Is it compulsory to end my URL with .git

Comment: Ideally it should because the git repo on central server is  a barre repository and hence it should be .git. In your case it looks like that the get parameters, r points to bare repo and h refers to the branch that you need to checkout.

Comment: So my URL with all the parameters is correct? Please check again. I have made some edits in my question.

Comment: I think you should add "log" to the url. Try 
git clone https://gdt.test.com/gitblit/log/mytest.git

Comment: What platform you are on ?