# `git remote add` is throwing a fatal error

Tags: linux, git, bash, ssh, server

I have followed this [tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) and made it to this line.

```
   git remote add production demo@server_domain_or_IP:root
```

I have a bare repo setup on my remote server and I have verified the username and domain are correct because I use the same user name and domain ( I actually use the IP address ) to ssh into the account.

I have a simple directory name `root` in the top level directory.

Yet I get this error.

> fatal: not a git repository ...

**What I tried**

I tried changing the folder name to `root.git` but this did nothing as I expected yet could not think of what else to try.

**Research**

[Receiving "fatal: Not a git repository" when attempting to remote add a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo)

I don't think this answer is correct, because a bare repo does not have a .git directory.  You should not need a .git directory for a folder to be a repo ( It could be a bare repo ).

Comment: Where is your repository within the filesystem structure of your server?

Comment: in the top under the name root... it does not have a .git folder, maybe this is why?

Comment: Do you mean directly under root like `/myRepo` or user root's home like `/home/root/myRepo`? Did you init the Repo with `git init`? I don't have a git repo here atm but thought if you did a `git init` it should have a directory `.git`

Comment: No root is the repo and it is in the top directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be in a git working directory to run this command.  It is the second answer down in the research link you produced.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but maybe try

```
/root
```

instead of

```
root
```

because

without the `/` it will search root in `/home/demo/root`.