# Error: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

My deployment to heroku was successful, but whenever I try and open the app it crashes. I check heroku logs and am getting these errors:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)State changed from starting to crashed 2015-12-22T12:36:13.277955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-12-22T12:36:15.736462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 15638 -e production`
2015-12-22T12:36:18.003961+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
2015-12-22T12:36:18.003980+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
2015-12-22T12:36:18.006461+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)
2015-12-22T12:36:18.006463+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question: At least try if this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo

Comment: I'm finding this error strange because I am definitely pushing to heroku from a git repo -- I've been pushing for the last few weeks without any such error, my app just crashed and this error showed up in heroku logs after a successful push to heroku from the same root file I've been pushing from for the past few weeks.

Comment: Maybe something broke then and files are missing. Try to initialize your cloud files once again. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderTrust, I'm building for a project so continuing to build locally and returning to these errors after the deadline. Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: any solution @anishasri