# ProcessBuilder don't accept git repo path

Tags: java, git

Hello i have problem with path to repo in ProcessBuilder. I had same problem once, but that solution didn't work this time. And my error looks

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Any ideas why the path is not working? repository root is

```
public static final String REPOSITORY_ROOT = "C:\\Workspace-git\\";
```

[image]

Solution

```
ProcessBuilder ps= new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"git","pull",RepositoryConstants.REPOSITORY_ROOT+"cl-testowy"});
        ps.directory(new File(RepositoryConstants.REPOSITORY_ROOT+"cl-testowy"));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably receive this error because you are not in the right local `git` directory, see :

[Receiving “fatal: Not a git repository” when attempting to remote add a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo)

What you can do, is to tell your process to be run from a particular directory with the [directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) method, in your case :

```
ps.directory(new File(REPOSITORY_ROOT+"cl-testowy"));
```