# can't git add . files, how do i git add , the right way?

Tags: git, git-add

Hi I am new on ruby on rails, I am creating an app with the ruby on rails version 3. I am having trouble, I have a lot of files to add. I type command `git status` and the following comes up , then I typed `git add .` and nothing happens. What am I missing?

> $ git status
>
> On branch master
>   Untracked files:
>    (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
.CFUserTextEncoding
.DS_Store
.bash_history
.bash_profile
.bash_sessions/
.bashrc
.bundle/
.cache/
.config/
.gem/
.gitconfig
.heroku/
.local/
.mkshrc
.mplayer/
.netrc
.node-gyp/
.npm/
.oracle_jre_usage/
.profile
.rvm/
.ssh/
.subversion/
.viminfo
.zlogin
.zshrc
Applications/
Desktop/
Documents/
Downloads/
FrostWire/
Library/
Movies/
Music/
Pictures/
Public/
RubymineProjects/
homebrew/
keys.txt
workspace/
```

Comment: Don't make a git repo directly in your home directory.

Comment: how can i changed to where it needs to be?

Comment: seems you are not inside your project folder. after running the `rails new` command, move into your web app directory first by using `cd project directory` command

Comment: What is the name of your application?

Comment: Did you store it in `RubymineProjects` or under `workspace` perhaps?

Comment: Guessing maybe you have GIT_DIR set in a startup file pointing to your ~ because otherwise u should get `fatal: not a git repo...` when not within a repo..  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23975989/631619

Comment: i have created like 3 app on accident with heroku when i only needed one, using heroku create command , this the name of the last app i made "rocky-garden-26832"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have initialized your home directory as a git repo.

If you are very new to git, I would recommend you to install a Gui client to use git.
 There are many of them, just google it.

If you still want to use the terminal approach, read on:

**Follow these steps**

- first, use the `cd` command to navigate to the your project folder, like :

  ```
  $ cd ~/path/to/the/your/project
  ```
- then, use `git status` to see if your project folder is already a git repo. If not, use `git init` to make your project a git repo.
- further then you can add all your project files normally using `git add --all ./` (if you what to add them all)

Answer (score -1):

check list of remotes using

```
git remote
```

Install git-cola UI use for stage/unstage and commit files easily. You can also easily see the changes made in files.

In ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install git-cola
```

Move to your app directory and write command

```
cola
```

It will display all changes in file. Stage it and commit it.

Comment: Install git cola and stage files. Its the same way as you use git add .

Comment: check .git file in your app directory. is it there or not?

Comment: check the git submodules if any under app.