# Android Project Not Opening

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I downloaded the files from https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser

And then clicked on File > Open and selected the extracted folder.

But I am not able to open it. It is showing errors like "Default" name not found, etc.

Can anyone tell us step by step process on how to open that project file to work with and edit things?

I am a noob, so any details explanation is highly appreciable.

Comment: project setting direction is already given on github -https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser#setting-up-the-project

Comment: I opened the file in android studio, I already have git installed, so I ran the git command in that link in the folder as well as from the terminal in android studio, and I got the message "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: this will help -http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630763/6291914

Comment: Some folders don't have any files. And the total file size is less than 1-2 MB

Comment: did you run this command git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: I downloaded the file, got a zip file. I extracted it, and opened the folder which have the files. First ran the command git init, then the command which you said. Still nothing in the folders.

Comment: i have imported code using clone   in an empty folder open git bash try running these 2 commands git clone https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser.git then git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: When I ran the first command in an empty folder, I got the error: "fatal: repository 'github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser.git' does not exist"

Comment: use https before link

Comment: Ok, the first command ran correctly, when I run the second command, I got the error: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
To overcome that I ran git init, and then git submodule update --init --recursive but nothing happened, except a (master) is added now in the end.

Comment: you dont have to run git init just go into .git directory and run second command

Comment: I don't see any .git directory in that folder.