# Not a git repository after cloning a git repository

Tags: git

After cloning a git repository using

```
git clone https://github.com/********/****.git
```

I just tried to push something into the same git repo, but it shows:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How can I fix this?

Comment: please Read <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving "fatal: Not a git repository" when attempting to remote add a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo)

Comment: Check if the directory you are trying to pull has a .git folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you forgot to switch to the project directory or the clone process was not successful. Please check carefully.

Answer (score 7):

You probably forgot to switch to the project directory after pulling the project.

`$> cd PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT_DIR` can solve your problem.

Comment: there is no any directory in the name of that git repo

Comment: @Nikhil, let's say i'm clonning project using command `$> https://github.com/fewlinesofcode/myProj.git`, then, after clonning my next command will be `$> cd myProj`. `myProj` is the directory name if it's not set manually. You should replace `myProj` with the name of your project