# Local git repositoy crashed resulting in "Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)"

Tags: git

My computer crashed and now I encounter problems with my local git repository.

```
git status
```

result in

```
shows fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I am in the correct repository and I can also see the .git folder which contains the following files / folders.

[image]

I tried

```
git init
```

which resulted in

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/dev/myproject/.git/
```

However it still does not work (git status result in the error message mentioned above).

Is there any way to repair my local repository? I have some work in there which I haven't pushed yet and will lose otherwise.

Comment: Why not just clone again to another folder and diff tool to move your changes in? Or even just overwrite the new clone files with your working folder files, using copy command.

Comment: Thanks, but the moment my repository crashed I wasn't on the branch where my chenges reside in.

Comment: Is `git fsck` working?

Comment: Back up your broken repo before you start messing with it

Comment: The image shows a file named `HEAD` is present, but check to see if its contents are valid. (Incidentally, using images in questions is something of an anti-pattern: see, e.g., https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @sbat: No, it didn't. Did also result in "shows fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: @torek. Many thanks. The file head looked something like NUL|NUL|NUL... I copied ref: refs/heads/master in it and it was working again.

Comment: Link (accepted answer is not the one for here, but there is one in there that matches): https://stackoverflow.com/q/4630704/1256452

Answer (score 2):

In the .git folder, there should be a file HEAD. In that file, type

> ref: refs/heads/master

If the file does not exist, you can create it

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a corrupt file HEAD in  the .git folder. After editing it so it contains a reference to a valid branch like this

```
refs/heads/master
```

the repository is working again.

Comment: How did you fix it?