# git add causes corrupt index error

Tags: php, git, drupal

I am having a bit of a problem here with git. I have a drupal set up. 
I have the proper .gitignore set up.

everytime i do **git add .** and **git status**. i get **index file corrupt** error.

I followed this [How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/index-file-corrupt) to fix it, but it keeps coming back. I tried removing entire .git folder. but it didnt work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean remove `.git`?/ After that you have nothing

Comment: yes the entire .git folder. after removing it, i had nothing. so initiated a new git repo. and do git add . again. but the same error happened.

Comment: Mhmm, my suggestion: try delete hole git project, then try clone it again and see if it works. By the way, in your provided link says: remove only index file, not hole .git folder...

Comment: cant delete the project. i tried both, removed index file and whole .git folder. neither works.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact problem.

I figured out my problem was that there were two other .git folders in subdirectories.  I had cloned two repos into these sub folders.  I removed these two .git folders and I was able to use git again.

To find these other .git folders I ran this command:

```
find . -name ".git" -type d
```