# xcode index file corrupt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hi I have inherited an xcode project after a developer left the company. I need to add a new image to an iphone app but when i add the image i get an error:

```
"error: bad index file sha1 signature fatal: index file corrupt"
```

I have been looking for a solution to this and found some articles about deleting the 'build' file and this will resolve the issue. But i cannot find this file in the directory or in xcodes project view. Can someone point me the in right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/index-file-corrupt

Comment: Im not a mac guy, so is the command hes talking about done in terminal?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that in terminal.

Comment: Tried it and got 'not a git repository (or ay of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Stack overflow wont allow me to answer my own question but i got to the answer in the end. The git repository was the issue but i had to view my project on our dev box in windows with the option to see hidden files, eventually i found the index file in the hidden .git foler and deleted it. fix the issue!! thanks rishi

Comment: you can post your answer and accept that, there is no issue in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean the build folder press on your keyboard `option + shift + command + K`

Or go to `Product(while pressing option key)->clean build folder`