# .git folder corrupted: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: windows, git

My Virtual machine crashed while trying to merge one local branch to another. After I restarted that machine I receive the following error when trying to do anything Git-Related:

```
git pull
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

There is a .git - subfolder which (on first sight) looks like just an ordinary git-folder containing .config .HEAD and so on

*(Please don't mark this as duplicate for those questions where the op was just in the wrong directory. That is NOT the issue here)*

Contents of the .git-Folder:
[image]

(update) I just checked the source files I changed. They are completely destroyed containing only "NUL" - Values. So I guess there is no way I can retrieve any of my work done. So Checkout and start all over again it is, then.

Comment: Question: Do you have any local work which you would care if it were lost?

Comment: kindof. I guess I know why you are asking. :) Of course I could simply checkout into a new directory but I would prefer not to. It is about 2h work I will lose

Comment: You can checkout into a new directory and then copy the code (but not the .git directory) from your current directory

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error after a system hard power off. The `.git` folder was no longer recognized and my local branches and commited files (but not pushed) seems to be gone. I recover my day work with the following steps :

- Create a new folder and reinit a clean repo on the main branch
- Go to your old `.git` folder and make a recursive copy in the sub tree for the `hooks`, `info`, `logs`, `objects` and `ref` folders to your freshly created clean `.git` folder. (I do not overwrite existing files)

And that's it. My local files and branches have been recovered. I think some git cache files and head meta were corrupted.

edit: Here is a more detail and cleaner way to do this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853585/4904074