# Eclipse Mavan Project Corrupted

Tags: git, eclipse, github, selenium-webdriver

I don't know how and why one of my Eclipse project got corrupted, it is just showing empty packages.
Please find below Screenshot

[image]

I am assuming that this happened with one of the git commit last month
I have checked and tried doing this
[Eclipse project got corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556155/eclipse-project-got-corrupt)
but the files under .git\refs no where it is showing any stashes

Could someone please help me to recover this project?

EDIT:

This is what I have in my repository.

[image]

Comment: The `(in bin)` indicates that you have imported a directory `bin` as project, which does not seem to be the right one to import as project. Show what you have in your Git repository (which files and folders) and tell the location of the project (right-click the project _Properties: Resource: Location_).

Comment: edited my post, please check and help !!

Comment: Yes, that looks like a Maven project, but the `pom.xml` file is missing. You first have to restore the POM file. Try right-clicking the project and choosing _Restoring from Locale History_. If this does not work, restore it from Git: is the deletion shown in the _Git Staging_ view or did you already commit it? After the `pom.xml` file has been restored, right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._