# Version Control GIT-Commit is showing no changes

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control

In Android Studio, when I'm trying to commit, it is showing No Changes. I have done a lot of changes since my last commit, it's been almost 20 days from my last commit. I don't why it's not detecting changes.

Due to no commits, push is also not working.

I'm getting the below error when I open version control in android studio

[image: ERROR IMAGE IN ANDROID STUDIO - VERSION CONTROL]

Comment: did you try to track changes from terminal also ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, can you tell how to do that. @DhananjaySingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.My Git Index File Was Corrupted.

Found solution in below link.

[Found solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git)

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone who has **GIT working in Android Studio's terminal but not directly in Android Studio** -

In my case, I was able to see the changes and new files list in the terminal when using Git commands (like `git status` or `git add --all`) but when I tried to commit by going to GIT -> Commit in Android Studio, it showed - **No changes to commit** when I clearly had changes to commit.

The solution which worked for me: Try to check if Git and Github are enabled in Android Studio. (It was enabled in my case, however, I disabled it and then again enabled both and restarted Android Studio and **it worked**.

> File -> Settings -> Plugins -> (search for git) -> make sure it is checked (if it is already checked, uncheck and then check again) and click OK

> Now, restart Android Studio