# Error while checkout git branch

Tags: git

I am new to GIT. Previously I was working on one of the branch and was having some pending changes too and my machine got crashed. On my new machine I installed git again and did a clone of the repository(develop). When I am trying `git status` or `git checkout mybranch`

I am getting below error:-

```
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Can you please suggest something how can I resolve this?

Comment: could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git

Comment: I have seen this link. I checked the current branch is showing as develop when i run git branch command. But I want to understand if I run commands mentioned in above link will shift me to the branch which I was working previously?

Comment: `git reset` does not change current branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git)