# android studio commit changes on Team services/tfs

Tags: android, git, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Team foundation services to upload android studio projects on TFS server 
I the project is added successfully to server using 
`VSC -> Import into version control -> Import into Team services git`

But when i tried to change any code in the activity and click `VSC -> Commit changes` a pop up message return `no changes detected` why??

Comment: Are there any error messages showing there? What about commit the changes with `git commit ` command directly ?

Comment: Same message when click commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstall the Git and re install it again also i started from zero to upload the projects and commit works fine

Answer (score 1):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Try to run command `$ git status` (You need to install [Git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) to run the command under the repo) to check if there are any error
  messages there. If get the error like this : `bad index file sha1 signature, fatal: index file corrupt`. Just try to delete the `index`
  file, then reset with below command (Reference this thread :[How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git)):

  `del .git\index
   git reset`

  To run the command : Install **Git bash** >> go to the git repository and right-click the project folder >> **Git bash here** >> Run the command in Git bash.
- Go to the file you have changed and **Right Click** >
  **Synchronize**,  then it will check against the last one manually. The commit again.

For Android studio with Git, you can reference [Version Control System using Git on Android Studio](https://medium.com/@akbarsha03/version-control-system-using-git-on-android-studio-a632eb00bea9).

[image]

Comment: @Amalo Install [Git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) >> go to the git repository and right-click the project folder >> Git bash here >> Run the command in Git bash

Comment: i re-install the Git and start from zero and all is okay but sometimes did't work !!